# Perguntas feitas sem pesquisa prévia

Tags: debate, perguntas

Por que algumas perguntas que claramente foram feitas **sem nenhuma pesquisa** são aceitas? Estava vendo as perguntas referentes a tag `java` e me deparei com esta,
"[Como criar uma classe em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67526/como-criar-uma-classe-em-java)"

Uma rápida pesquisa no Google já responderia esta pergunta mas aqui obteve relevância, perguntas "óbvias" dessa forma não deveriam ser fechadas? Ou listada em "[Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"

Comment: Acho que vale, pois justamente quando você for fazer uma '_rápida pesquisa no google_' ela possa aparecer em primeiro lugar na lista, dando destaque ao SOpt, ;)

Comment: @Earendul - Acho que deveria transformar seu comentário em resposta.

Comment: @Earendul Mas qual a utilidade do botão "Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa" neste caso?

Comment: Boa pergunta esta ^^^ @DanielaMarquesdeMorais

Comment: Boa pergunta ;), talvez ela não demonstre esforço de pesquisa, mas com certeza é clara e é útil. Não sei se o objetivo do botão é que seja pressionado se os 3 motivos sejam satisfeitos ou apenas um ou dois deles...

Comment: A pergunta não mostrar esforço de pesquisa _pode_ fazer ela não merecedora de voto a favor, o que não tem nada a ver com fechar a pergunta. Não existe nenhum motivo de fechamento "Essa pergunta parece ser fora de escopo pois o autor não fez uma rápida pesquisa no Google antes". A pergunta ser simples pode não render muitos votos ao autor, mas isso não implica que ele não mereça uma resposta.

Comment: Nesse caso de útil ou não é o voto de cada um, a pergunta poderia até ficar negativada de votos, mas não suspensa

Comment: @Math Comentário esclarecedor!

Comment: No meu ponto de vista, se a pergunta está no escopo do SoPT, deva ser aceita normalmente, porém acho valido um comentário perguntando sobre as referencias que já foram utilizadas (neste caso)

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/732/pol%C3%ADtica-sobre-perguntas-de-n%C3%ADvel-rtfm?rq=1

Comment: Discordo do digníssimo novo moderador @Math só no ponto das perguntas simples render poucos votos. Elas costumam render muitos votos porque qualquer um pode qualificá-la. Perguntas simples são boas, só não pode deturpar o objetivo do site. E como foi dito, o objetivo do site é ser referência nas buscas. O problema é se a pergunta simples gerar resposta simples. Gerar link para outra referência sem agregar nada aqui. O link acima dá uma ideia boa de como as coisas costumam ou devem ser tratadas.

Comment: Acabo de ser criticado por fazer perguntas simples :D http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80182/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-git-init-e-git-init-bare

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Creio que se a pessoa abriu uma pergunta aqui no SOPT, e esteja dentro do escopo mesmo que seja muito simples, deve ser tratada como bem vinda, o que pode ter acontecido é o AP após ter feito essa "rápida pesquisa no google" não entendeu, ai abriu uma pergunta aqui para ver se alguém consegue explicar de outras formas/maneiras.

Mas, se aqui mesmo no SOPT já existir uma pergunta igual dai sim, marcar como duplicada ou demais casos que desqualificaria a pergunta, mas não pelo simples fato da pergunta ser simples.

Lembrando que o SOPT tem pessoas com muito conhecimento, mas também tem pessoas que estão iniciando os seus estudos e ambos podem se beneficiar/usufruir do SOPT.

Comment: Mas e quando o usuário já é avançado e faz perguntas básicas ou perguntas um pouco óbvias?

A intenção de quem cria a pergunta também importa? As vezes eu vejo perguntas que pra mim tem a clara intenção apenas agariar pontos para o criador.

Comment: Nesse caso temos que avaliar, o cara é tipo um @wallaceMaster que faz perguntas que é só p/ matar a curiosidade ? onde até para ele a pergunta tem pouca serventia, nesse caso eu analiso se merece pois apesar de ser mera curiosidade é uma coisa que "talvez" alguém use p/ alguma coisa isso fortalece a comunidade.

Comment: É, nunca saberemos a real intenção de quem posta, mas até as perguntas seguem um padrão, então...