# Pergunta de auto resposta para fins próprios

Tags: debate, perguntas, responder-a-si-mesmo

#### Situação

Eu tenho um dúvida então eu pesquiso para solucioná-la, passadas algumas semanas me surge a mesma dúvida, mas não recordo como eu resolvi, então pesquiso novamente.

#### Dúvida

Esta correto fazer uma pergunta de auto resposta que tenha fins próprios?
Na qual eu farei a pergunta e irei auto respondê-la para caso me surja novamente a dúvida apenas pesquise em meu repositório.

#### Vantagens (de meu ponto de vista)

- Pode solucionar o problema de outra pessoa.
- Gera informação para o site.

#### Desvantagens (de meu ponto de vista)

- Pode ser egoísta, já que tem fins de facilitar pesquisas futuras.

#### OBS

- [Relacionado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta) basicamente o segundo tópico (Faça perguntas...) me responde, exceto e fato dos fins de pergunta.
- Eu ia perguntar isso no chat, mas ficou um tanto grande.

Comment: Você pode perguntar e responder a si mesmo independente se é para ajudar a você mesmo ou aos outros. O importante é você fazer perguntas dentro do tópico, com clareza e respondíveis. E a resposta deve ser feita imaginando que você utilizou apenas as informações contidas no corpo da pergunta. Fazendo assim você estará dando a possibilidade de que outros se beneficiem dela, mesmo que o único interessado por ela a princípio seja somente você.

Comment: Compreendo, a pergunta que tenho é simples, de meu ponto de vista um pesquisa rápida já resolve, mas como  já é a terceira vez que tenho que pesquisar, pensei nesta possibilidade.

Comment: Resolvi oficializar meu comentário já com uma adição de texto respondendo ao seu comentário :)

Comment: Só uma pergunta pesquisaste aqui no SOpt ou fora?

Comment: Geralmente Fora, muitas vezes no SO.

Comment: Acho que "fins proprios" é o que move todos os seres vivos do planeta. Cada um deles. Se pertence a alguma comunidade e a escala do envolvimento nessa comunidade, varia de especie a especie e de individuo a individuo. Ou seja, maior lambança :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode perguntar e responder a si mesmo independente se sua intenção é ajudar a você mesmo ou aos outros. O importante é você fazer perguntas dentro do tópico, com clareza e respondíveis, e a resposta deve ser feita imaginando que você utilizou apenas as informações contidas no corpo da pergunta.

Fazendo assim você estará dando a possibilidade de que outros se beneficiem dela, mesmo que o único interessado por ela a princípio seja somente você.

Sobre perguntas simples, não há problema quanto a isso, como pode ver por exemplo nas perguntas listadas abaixo:

- [Questão simples demais feita por um "experiente"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2170/3117)
- [É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham facilmente (como alguns julgam) no Google?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4432/3117)
- [Perguntas feitas sem pesquisa prévia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4026/3117)

Sobre o assunto em questão (responder a si mesmo), pode ver as perguntas da tag [responder-a-si-mesmo](/questions/tagged/responder-a-si-mesmo)

Comment: E cuidado para não criar duplicatas.