# Pergunta fechada corretamente ou uso excessivo de poder?

Tags: debate

Recentemente tivemos uma pergunta no site que eu acho que não agradou a moderação, que foi esta:

[Soma, subtração, conversão de horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210468/20615)

Um pouco mais de uma hora, [a pergunta foi fechada pelo @bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210468/revisions#spacer-8c209d6d-a160-46ea-b8bc-d32deae9b12b). Até o momento, não vejo problemas.

[Analisando os comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas/210561#comment430352_210468), é possível entender exatamente o que o AP deseja e após edições a pergunta foi reaberta seguindo os trâmites da fila.

Após isso, [novamente a pergunta foi fechada pelo @bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210468/revisions) (dessa vez possuía um voto de outro usuário) pelo mesmo motivo e pelas ferramentas de moderação.

Não ligo da pergunta ser fechada, [inclusive porque a dúvida do AP foi sanada havia sido sana nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas#comment430353_210468). Só quis reabrir a pergunta para adicionar mais informações, o que não seria possível nos comentários.

Porém, o moderador fechou a mesma pergunta 2 vezes sem passar pela fila e "passando por cima" de 5 usuários ativos do site que votaram para reabrir a pergunta.

Com isso vem a dúvida:

A moderação é instruída a ter esse comportamento ou foi um abuso de poder?

#### Atualização

A pergunta foi reaberta novamente por mais 5 usuários diferentes (incluindo do autor da pergunta). A maior diferença da edição foi alterar o termo "hora" por "quantidade de tempo".

Comment: Olha eu posso estar enganado, mas não achei a pergunta de todo mal e concordo plenamente contigo, ela me parece simples e direta, mas sobre a parte de abuso de poder, creio que não tenha sido isto, eu posso estar enganado, mas entendi que ali foi uma *"prevenção"* misturada talvez com falta de atenção. Afinal de contas, até mesmo o mais experiente dos usuários do site pode estar equivocado :) ... ps: pra mim desde a primeira versão da pergunta estava clara (opinião minha), votei para reabrir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Note que eu não discordo do primeiro fechamento e sim do segundo. Falo do segundo porque ela foi reaberta por 5 pessoas, e foi fechada novamente após ter 2 respostas e o AP comentando que a dúvida estava sanada. Como você disse, ele queria saber apenas o básico.

Comment: Deixando minha contribuição, sou a favor de criação de diretrizes de recomendação. Essas diretrizes seriam tópicos no meta, aonde teriam critérios adicionais, além do Tour, e tópicos já postados no meta. Uma guia de recomendações para a moderação atuar. Minha opinião é que o que já foi implementado é insuficiente para deixar clareza nas decisões da moderação (minha opinião). Se nem a constituição de um país é suficiente para questões estruturais, imagine diretrizes de um site.
Fica aí minha contribuição!

Comment: Ah sim, entendi agora, realmente concordo isto também

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Eu não sei se os moderadores recebem algum treinamento ou instruções. A única coisa que eu sei que existe é [A teoria da Moderação](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: Tenho sérias críticas a este modelo, mas reconheço os benefícios. Mas já falando dos problemas:
1) O ser humano é dinâmico, e não estático. A mesma pessoa que obteve boa reputação pode cometer erros graves. Não existe nenhum impedimento quanto a isso. O "Youtube Hero" trabalha nesse modelo, e foi ferozmente criticado pela comunidade.
2) Reputação não é quantificável. A reputação é um valor subjetivo demais para convertemos em 'pontos'.
Por isso, eu defendo que a moderação faça 'Pacote de Emendas Constitucionais' para que eles decidam os melhores critérios para fechamento, etc.

Comment: Intervalo de tempo realmente dá para somar. Hora não. Meio dia e quinze não se soma com duas da tarde (quanto daria?). Agora um intervalo de doze horas e quinze minutos pode ser somado com um intervalo de c(qu)atorze horas sem problemas. Os numeros são os mesmos, mas são coisas diferentes. Da mesma forma não dá pra somarmos um quilograma com dois metros. Voltando ao C#, teria como se fazer a soma de dois DateTime?

Comment: @Bacco Então, mas não seria o caso de **uma resposta** explicar isso? Se o AP está com essa dúvida e até mesmo erro de conceito, quem deve sanar essas dúvidas são as respostas. Sobre a soma de DateTime, até onde **eu** conheço não é possível, pois você não pode somar o dia 01 com o dia 05, por exemplo. Todavia, você consegue adicionar ou subtrair anos/meses/dias/horas,minutos,etc e subtrair duas datas.

Comment: @Randrade talvez. Eu prefiro com a edição da pergunta mesmo, de qq forma só comentei aqui pra ajudar quem não entendeu o problema com o conceito de horas (o Jefferson explica isso na resposta aqui do meta, mas talvez o pessoal não leia tudo), e com seu edit achei que seria bom exemplificar.

Comment: @Bacco Eu não discuto isso, até porque não é a intenção aqui. Todavia, uma pessoa que desconhece do assunto, "somar horas" é algo comum de se dizer (não que esteja certo). Alguns exemplos seriam "somar" horas trabalhadas, timesshets, ponto eletrônico, etc. Cada um que abrir uma pergunta sobre esses ou assuntos similares poderão utilizar "horas", pois é o comum de se utilizar.

Answer (score 9):

Essa discussão tá parecendo um julgamento de alta instância de tão longas que estão as respostas. Eu sei que tem muita coisa envolvida, mas prefiro a simplicidade.

Minha reação com essa pergunta é: voto negativo e voto para fechar.

Voto negativo pois a pergunta não mostra esforço de pesquisa, como diz o *alt-text* do controle de voto.

> Nativo no c# não encontrei nada que não exija muito esforço e cálculos de conversão

Esse é o tipo de comentário que me faz questionar se proibir o uso de LMGTFY foi mesmo uma boa ideia para o Stack Overflow. Eis uma pesquisa mínima que atende o problema da questão:

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=intervalo%20de%20tempo%20em%20.net

Voto para fechar, pois realmente não está clara. Até ler a pergunta três vezes eu não sabia o que o OP realmente queria.

Eu sei que todos temos o desejo de ajudar. Nós pedimos esclarecimentos, editamos as perguntas, discutimos no meta etc... Mas quem pergunta também tem que fazer sua tarefa de casa.

Comment: **Quase** concordei com você - faltou pouco. Fato - se o AP usasse a sua pesquisa, ele teria resolvido o problema dele no GUJ - talvez nem tivesse criado uma conta no Stack Overflow. *Way to go.*

Comment: Mas ficou claro que é "um julgamento de alta instância" ;) A coisa era para ter sido simples demais. Queria ver você mais no site, até quando discorda de mim, pelo menos faz algum sentido.

Comment: Será que alguém possui algumas gravações para acelerar a coisa? :p
Então, não concordo muito com a sua opinião, pois o fato da [pesquisa prévia já foi tratada em outra pergunta no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4026/20615) e lendo o primeiro comentário do AP na pergunta, podemos entender realmente o que ele deseja. Todavia, a intenção aqui não é a saber se o fechamento foi ou não correto, e sim o moderador fechar a pergunta 2x, sendo que na segunda a pergunta havia sido reaberto por 5 pessoas.

Comment: @Randrade essa pergunta tem potencial para uma guerra de reabertura. Eu mesmo a fecharia como estava quando escrevi a resposta, caso estivesse aberta. Acredito que mais pessoas fariam o mesmo. A pergunta ainda precisa de mais trabalho de elaboração até que seja unânime a opinião de que ela não deve ser fechada.

Comment: @Renan Eu particularmente não vejo como ser mais claro. O AP quer apenas saber como fazer isso: `1hr + 1hr = 2hrs`. Agora, unanimidade é algo meio complicado de ter no site, pois vários critérios distintos fazem as pessoas votarem, e nem todos concordam com os critérios de todos. Todavia, estamos fugindo um pouco do foco original da pergunta aqui no meta, então não sei se seria adequado prolongar esse assunto.

Comment: @Randrade a pergunta poderia ser mais clara, e até canônica, da seguinte forma. `Título: Intervalos de tempo em C#. Corpo da pergunta: Como faço para trabalhar com intervalos de tempo em C#? Por exemplo, eu gostaria de somar dois intervalos e obter a quantidade total de tempo.` Todo o resto é ruído. Quando você tem mais ruído do que sinal, você tem uma pergunta que não é clara.

Comment: @Renan O AP usou o termo `horas`. Ele não precisa saber que deveria utilizar "intervalo de tempo" na pergunta. Se as respostas deveriam explicar o conceito, a conversa é outra. Mas se o AP desconhecia esse termo (não posso afirmar isso), não seria possível utilizá-lo, não concorda? Sem falar que nos comentários ele explica mais e como em muitos casos, lendo as respostas você entende a pergunta.

Comment: Eu concordo que o termo intervalo de horas deixaria mais claro a pergunta, porem no momento eu não pensei nesse termo até mesmo por influencia aqui da empresa pois todos tratam esse intervalo de tempo, com o termo "hora", então provavelmente estava viciado neste termo e por isso eu utilizei, porem como diversos usuários identificaram que o termo hora estava não estava correto, quase ninguém exceto o ramaral, se deu ao trabalho de alterar o termo para "unidades de tempo", já o outro administrador apenas disse estar errada e não quis saber de tentar editar a pergunta ou se quer entender a mesma.

Comment: Como eu já li diversas vezes aqui neste tópico, a pergunta tinha potencial se fosse feito ajustes nos termos, pelo meu ver não estava totalmente perdida, e existiu vários pedidos de reabertura, o correto nao seria algum adm dar 5 minutos de atenção na pergunta e tentar me ajudar a esclarecer? já que diversas pessoas entenderam corretamente minha duvida.

Answer (score 6):

Este é um caso muito mais claro que deveria ficar aberto e fecharam: [Uma pergunta que pede uma informação canônica é opinião?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5965/101) No entanto eu deixei fecharem.

Esse é um caso que as respostas podem ser divergentes e não tem como saber qual está certa. Claramente o AP não quis esclarecer e aceitou algo que pode ser o que ele queria, mas pode não ser, porque a maioria das pessoas não entendem do assunto e vão na intuição. Aí fica tudo errado, a pergunta, as respostas. E as pessoas achando que aquilo instrui. O AP deixou claro nos comentários que ele não entende do assunto e não quis mostrar o que quer de forma não ambígua. A avaliação dele que esta é a resposta é baseado, no "funciona no que eu estou fazendo", não no funciona sempre que eu precisar disto.

Eu farei uma canônica sobre o assunto já que a maioria das pessoas se confundem.

Usei a prerrogativa de moderador porque é uma pergunta não clara. Não tem as informações suficientes para ser respondida adequadamente. Eu sei que é controverso pelo fato das pessoas acharem uma coisa equivocada.

É possível debater mas os moderadores podem e devem resolver problemas independente de uma parte da comunidade concordar. Outra parte concorda. Eu evito ao máximo agir assim, mas tem caso que precisa. E certamente se esperasse mais não teriam só dois votos para fechar.

Dá para salvá-la? Dá. Mas no momento não. A versão atual está essencialmente com o mesmo problema que havia no primeiro fechamento, então concordar com o primeiro é concordar com o segundo.

Ok, a discordância que está com o mesmo problema, mas está. Continua não dizendo a que está realmente se referindo em algo que é ambíguo.

A pergunta não deve ser removida, mas deve ficar claro que ela não está clara. Cada um confie por seu próprio risco.

Outras pessoas podem dar sua opinião sobre abuso de poder. Embora por definição, não é. Mesmo se a decisão estiver errada que nem é o foco deste debate.

Comment: Você é moderador do site, mas isso não quer dizer que você sabe o que o AP pensa, muito menos que você "sabe tudo", para afirmar que a sua resposta estará certa e todas as outras estão erradas. E o simples fato de você escolher quando deixar a resposta fechada ou aberta apenas por causa de sua resposta confirma um pouco a minha premissa. Se a pergunta não merecesse permanecer aberta, nem você poderia responder, já que se trata da mesma coisa e não mudou nada por parte do AP. Se acha que as respostas estão erradas e a sua estará certa, prove, mas não culpe o AP pro isso.

Comment: Diferente da pergunta que você linkou em sua resposta, você foi para o meta perguntar (será que pq a resposta era sua?). Mas nesse caso você não foi? Sem falar que a pergunta que você disse que "deixou fecharem", a [minha resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5966/20615) justificando o motivo do fechamento foi bem aceita, o que poderia justificar o motivo dela permanecer fechada.

Comment: Você também não sabe o que ele pensa. A pergunta nunca deveria ter sido reaberta até o problema ter sido resolvido, o que não aconteceu até agora. Mas eu sei que ali há ambiguidade e é preciso ficar claro que há um problema nesse sentido. Eu sei como funciona o cálculo de horário. Salvo todo mundo que estuda isto estiver errado também. "E o simples fato de você escolher quando deixar a resposta fechada ou aberta apenas por causa de sua resposta confirma um pouco a minha premissa" não entendi do que está falando. Eu não respondi nada. Não dá para responder.

Comment: Não culpei o AP por nada além da pergunta não estar clara. Quanto às respostas o que eu posso fazer é negativar se eu achar que merece. Nem sei se eu iria ao meta. Estou com pouco tempo disponível, iria ver o que fazer. Eu pensei em fazer algo, mas só faria com o tempo disponível pra não sair acusando alguém de estar agindo de má fé.

Comment: [Este comentários do AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas#comment430352_210468) explica exatamente o que ele quer. Somente você e mais uma pessoa, até o momento, concordam com o fechamento. Fora isso 8+ concordam com a abertura da pergunta, então acho que tem algo errado. Sobre a resposta, você disse que **iria fazer uma canônica sobre o assunto**, se você se referiu à uma outra pergunta, eu entendi errado e peço desculpa por isso.

Comment: Não estou julgando má fé de ninguém, e sim "uso abusivo de poder", pois você passou por cima de votos de 8+ usuários do site e é por isso que vim ao meta. Se você negativar ou não, eu não me importo e nem viria aqui por isso, pois acho besteira alguém reclamar por negativos.

Comment: TL;DR: BDFL? Tipo o Guido van Rossum?

Comment: Eu acho que não explica, eu acho que continua confuso., E acho que sei avaliar isso. Acho que a maioria das pessoas não sabem e vou falar sobre isso no site assim que der. Não sei desses números e eles não fazem algo ser certo. Se só o número de pessoas que acham algo fosse o critério para decidir algo não precisava de moderadores. Não existe uso abusivo de poder de boa fé. A moderação tem a prerrogativa de passar por cima de todos votos dados. No Programmers isso vivia acontecendo e em geral não dava problema.

Comment: Uma das coisas que o Gabe me disse que moderação não é democracia (ñ dá p/ por todo contexto aqui, mas era pra deixar claro que eu não preciso de aprovação da comunidade para fazer algo que eu julgo certo.

Comment: Inclusive esses dias um usuário reclamou de mim pela primeira vez. Achei que viria muito antes e seria de um usuário novato. Não foi, foi um bem ativo, não vou dizer quem, mas você sabe quem é. Analisaram e não viram problema, só me falaram pra chamar outro moderador quando pode ter conflito de interesse, coisa que normalmente eu faço, não o fiz naquela situação que reclamaram porque não agi como moderador ali. Inclusive nessa sobre horário tem sinalização em coisa minha e deixei outro moderador cuidar. Sou muito consciente do que posso ou não fazer.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado basicamente isto. Tem que sr assim. Inclusive um dos motivos para os moderadores serem vitálios é não sofrer pressão da comunidade. Claro que sofre mesmo assim. Sempre que eu faço algo que desagrada alguns minhas postagens começam ter pouca votação :D

Comment: @bigown O que não explica? Ele apenas quer saber como chegar em "1 + 1 = 2". O que não tem de claro nisso? E o fato de você não entender algo é motivo para usar os poderes de moderador? Se 8+ entenderam e **você** não entendeu nós que estamos equivocados? Eu concordo com o que o Gabe disse, que "moderação não é democracia", mas ele disse que você poderia passar por cima de usuários ativos e que "entendem" o site apenas porque **você** não entendeu a pergunta?

Comment: Sem falar que nos primeiros comentários já existe conflito de interesses, pois aqueles comentários podem ser julgados rudes (não somente o seu). Se você está envolvido em algo, você não deveria deixar o post para outro moderador então? Você mesmo disse que até flag você teve e isso não seria motivos para induzir um comportamento "tendencioso", mesmo que indiretamente?

Comment: Não é o caso do que está sendo debatido, mas 5 + +7 pode dar 12 ou 2 e vai um, depois eu posto sobre isso. Eu acho que 8 não entenderam como a maioria das pessoas não entendem, não irei repetir isso, aguarde, aí você avalia. Se 8 analfabetos e o Einstein se reunir pra tomar uma decisão de física, você vai confiar na democracia? Não, eu não estou dizendo que existem 8 analfabetos aqui, e muito menos que eu sou Einstein. Apenas estou desqualificando a democracia como m´todo para resolver isto. 8 pessoas poderia dizer que 1 +1 é 3, e pelo seu critério deveria ser aceito como verdade.

Comment: O Gabe disse que eu poderia fazer o que eu achasse correto e necessário para o bom andamento do site sem me preocupar se os usuários discordam (claro  que estou fazendo uma simplificação aqui). Se foi certo ou não é outra questão, isto é passível de debate mesmo. Embora não foi isso que foi proposto nesse debate. Seria mais produtivo um debate sobre o assunto, não sobre abuso de poder, mas já que ele foi aberto, eu respondo ao que me cabe. Tudo o que você diz sobre eu não entender, vale para você não ter entendido também. O tempo mostrará. Se eu estiver errado eu volto atrás sem problema.

Comment: Se eu apenas comentar me desqualificar por ter conflito de interesses então vou só fechar e não escrever mais nada, não vou apontar problemas, instruir, nada, só fechar e ir embora. Você está confundindo bem as coisas. Conflito de interesses é outra coisa. A flag foi sobre outro motivo. Até existe a possibilidade de ser tendencioso pelo que você disse. Você pode ser tendencioso por querer responder, então não poderia ter votado para reabrir. Talvez não poderia opinar sobre o fechamento. Isto está muito mais próximo de conflito de interesses e mesmo assim eu acho que não é, senão engessa demais

Comment: Você não se preocupou em instruir o AP. Você colocou apenas links que raramente ele entenderia. Depois disso que você fez um bom comentário, quando a dúvida dele já estava sanada. 
Eu votei para reabrir e aguardei mais pessoas que concordam comigo. Não vim para o meta por aquilo, diferente do que várias pessoas costuma fazer. Só vim depois que você fechou **sem passar pela fina de análise**, por isso a dúvida é sobre "poder" e não sobre a pergunta. Acho desnecessário comentar a parte do Einstein, pois todos que votaram podem se sentir ofendido com isso.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que a pergunta está sendo votada para reabrir novamente, e como estou esperando a conclusão aqui, nenhum dos votos são meus.

Comment: Agora, será que você que não entendeu a pergunta ou está confundindo com [esta pergunta que foi aberta por causa da outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210776/20615)?

Comment: Coloquei links porque ele disse que eu não sei nada. Já fiz um nota pra dizer que não estava fazendo uma comparação com as pessoas porque eu tinha certeza que isso seria pensado, só não esperava que minha nota fosse ignorada. Não vou repetir sobre o que eu já respondi antes porque vamos ficar em círculos. Essa nova também não está lá muito clara, com o comentário já dá para entender, embora acho que está triscando a amplitude, mesmo assim não parece caso de fechar.

Comment: O fato de você comentar significa que você pensou e que mais pessoas poderiam pensar, mas eu não achei nada demais, apenas comentei. Agora,  você escolher "se fecha ou deixa aberto" me parece que você acha que é alguém "superior" por ser um moderador. A fila de análise existe para isso e temos muitas pessoas qualificadas para fazer esse papel. Se nossa opinião não serve, seria melhor colocar mais alguns moderadores e vocês tomam conta de tudo isso.

Comment: Bem eu entendo que muitos não podem ter entendido a questão, detalhe eu tentei alterar a mesma mais de 3 vezes e sempre que eu voltava pra questao alguém tinha editado ele e tinha voltado pro que estava eu acabei desistindo (não sei se foi erro meu ou algo estranho aconteceu).
Infelizmente o que eu recebi do bigown não foi uma instrução de como eu poderia melhorar minha questão ou o que poderia estão confundindo ele. em momento nenhum eu disse que não tinha conhecimento de como efetuar o processo da "soma" muito pelo contrario na própria pergunta estava comentando que já existia o processo.

Comment: Se vc mesmo viu que as duas respostas me atendiam, mesmo assim vc não tentou nem entender o que eu estava questionando, e se deu ao trabalho de tentar editar a questão, como diversas outras pessoas tentaram. A impressão desde o inicio, foi que você queria se mostrar superior, deixou promessas de messias e não explicou nem ajudou com 1 bit de informação. Infelizmente você foi e continua sendo bem arrogante, se o adm e vitalicio blz mas faça valer a pena e construa um forum com educação e tentativa de ajuda e nao apenas "ta uma bosta sua pergunta" igual vc deixou transparecer.

Comment: Realmente como sitou o Randrade que eu agradeço muito tanto pelo apoio na questão, como aqui, e que você não me instruiu de forma nenhuma.

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio eu não podia responder o que você quer, o rsto tudo eu disse. Quando você faz uma pergunta deve ser porque não saber. Quando alguém que sabe está tentando te mostrar que aquele conceito está errado, e você começa fazer gracinha, não parece que seja eu que me coloco como superior. Mas se for o caso, você quer que quem te ajude? Alguém inferior? Aí você vai aprender errado. Eu fui colocando tudo o que você estava perguntando e o que dá para ajudar. Falei no que não dava. Aí você mostrou que não estava interessado em diálogo. Mesmo assim continuei.

Comment: Por sorte não obteve uma resposta que soma dois horários porque isto é impossível e por isso nenhuma biblioteca permite fazer essa soma. Mas obrigado por ter dito isto, conforme meus argumentos aqui no meta. Ninguém conseguiu editar a pergunta. Ninguém sabe o que você quer e até não está escrito em lugar algum. Quando você quiser dialogar, talvez dê para ajudar mais, mas só reclamando não evolui. Não posso controlar a impressão que você teve.

Comment: Eu tentei ajudar. Eu tive a impressão que você começou tumultuar, posso até estar enganado porque é só minha impressão. Mesmo assim não desisti de você. Um moderador tem que fazer um monte de coisa, entre ele curar o conteúdo do site. Eu preferia em vez de tr toda essa discussão que o esforço fosse colocado para resolver o problema que está lá. Exageros não vão ajudar a discussão. Toda falta de edução foi sua. Justamente por eu escrever uma coisa e você ler outra que reproduziu aqui só causou problemas.

Comment: @bigown Veja bem o que você disse. Você falou que o conceito estava errado, que ele estava fazendo gracinha, e que você colocou tudo o que foi pedido. Porém, em seu primeiro comentário você postou um link para w Wikipedia (em inglês) que se pesquisar por "hour" ou "time" não terá resultados. No próximo, você coloca um sobre o `DateTime`, mas mesmo assim criticou a resposta que fala disso. E no outro postou dois links para um site que fala sobre "Falsehoods programmers believe about time" mas ele não fala nada que *não é possível somar duas datas*.

Comment: Sobre a parte da edição dele, ele editou por que eu o instruí [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468/soma-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-convers%C3%A3o-de-horas#comment430357_210468). Porém, ele pensou que era para descartar o resto, o que não foi a minha ideia. Eu só tentei ajudar a deixar a pergunta "mais clara", visto que nesse momento a mesma estava fechada por "não ser clara". Após ele tentar novamente, outro usuário pensou que ele editou sem saber e reverteu para a minha edição. Não teve nenhum erro de edição da pergunta e sim falta de entendimento entre comentários em off

Comment: Ele perguntou se tinha uma biblioteca que faz isso. Naquele momento realmente não dei uma solução direta, mas mostrei que a biblioteca padrão faz. Esse não é o problema da pergunta. Os comentários servem pra ir construindo o conhecimento. Por esse *link* ela começou esclarecer que queria algo que não pode ser feito. As outras partes dos comentários que eu falo sobre não ser possível somar dois horários não importa? Se começar pegar as coisas seletivamente, eu nem perco mais tempo aqui. Eu pedi para ele dizer o que ele estava querendo somar. O que um mvce bem simples ajudaria muito.

Comment: Se quiser dizer que o que eu coloquei não foi suficiente, blz, pode ser. Assim como não tem informação suficiente para responder. "Todo mundo" resolveu achar que eu não sabia o que eu estava falando e ignorou. Aí deu nisso. Se eu não estava claro nos meus comentários poderiam pedir pra eu tentar esclarecer.

Comment: Seu primeiro comentário foi apenas um link, repito, **em inglês**. Mas, em nenhum momento eu falei que o primeiro fechamento foi errado. Se o link foi entendido como rude ou outra coisa, isso não é a questão aqui. Porém, após o meu comentário com **um exemplo funcional em código** e o AP falando que é isso que ele precisa, você ainda insistiu em outros comentários que foram para o outro lado. Então, da mesma forma que você disse que eu peguei comentários seletivamente, você postou os demais sem ao menos ler o meu comentário, o do AP sobre o que queria e o do outro usuário que também comentou.

Comment: Chega, você está falando que eu não fiz algo que eu fiz, e mesmo que eu não tivesse feito, não teria como saber. Eu não disse que não leu, apenas que pinçou aqui só o que não ajuda mostrar que eu tentei ajudar resolver a questão. Deixou de ser produtivo.

Comment: Seguindo a sua lógica, você apenas respondeu o comentário que acha que o AP estava "tumultuando" (dizeres seu). Somente após aqueles comentários e a confirmação do AP que a pergunta foi reaberta. E mesmo assim, você fechou novamente pelo mesmo motivo. Se os comentários servem para "construir conhecimento" e dois exemplos, juntamente com a resposta do AP, não são conhecimento, o que seria?
Agora, se acha que as respostas estão erradas, você pode negativar, é um direito seu. Porém, para falar que está errada, você deve ao menos entender a pergunta, não?

Comment: @bigown Em nenhum momento eu disse isso, eu disse apenas que "seguindo a sua lógica" seria isso. Agora, eu repito **mais uma vez**. Eu não abri esse post pelo **primeiro** fechamento, falo isso na pergunta. Abri isso por causa do **segundo** fechamento, mesmo após 5 pessoas reabrirem a pergunta pela fila de análise e o AP falar o que ele queria nos comentários.

Comment: Apenas mais uma coisa. Você disse que foi aconselhado a "chamar outro moderador" caso ocorresse "conflito de interesse". Agora, uma pergunta onde você mesmo disse [que sinalizaram coisa sua](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6064/pergunta-fechada-corretamente-ou-uso-excessivo-de-poder#comment23214_6065) isso não se enquadraria em conflito de interesse? Se sim, como você mesmo disse, não deveria "chamar" um outro moderador?

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio nste momento estou vendo a sessão do TSE. Você deve ficar horrorizado com os juízes de um tribunal superior falando para o outro que ele está errado. Pelo seu critério eles não são humildes. Mas não adianta insistir, não vai levar a lugar algum. Você considera "tem coisa errada aí" arrogância, mas "tá tirando com minha cara" humildade. Meu critério é diferente do seu. O meu focou no problema. Pode ser que não fiz da melhor forma, que não ajudou, mas ninguém questionou **o que** eu disse, questionaram eu ter dito. Por isso deu toda confusão. O diálogo foi interrompido, ñ por mim.

Comment: Sei que você está cansado do assunto, mas acho que você tem que fechar as coisas do jeito que fechou mesmo. Não concordo com nenhum de vocês sobre a pergunta ser ruim, ainda mais depois que o randrade editou (mas quem sou eu?), mas anyway, continue sendo o moderador que você está sendo, +1

Answer (score 6):

Creio que aqui o ponto deveria ser o como tratar a questão. Para alguns, ela estava clara (eu incluso). Para outros, ela tinha falhas lógicas que a tornavam irreparáveis. Mas quais falhas lógicas? Não seria melhor manejar essa tal falha de outra maneira?

Bem, a falha lógica foi adicionar horas/datas, não foi? Realmente, 10h da manhã + 22h34 da noite durante a novela não tem um resultado com sentido... mas trabalhar por 4h e almoçar por 2h faz você ficar ocupado por 6h. E considerando essas 6h, se o dia começa às 8h da manhã, 8h da manhã + 6h daria as 14h da tarde.

Creio que é análogo a parte de somar pontos e vetores na geometria analítica. Eu exploro um pouco esse conceito de entidades [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198363/64969) (só toquei de leve, mas me era relevante no contexto do problema). Intervalos de tempo seriam vetores, e pontos no tempo seriam pontos no plano. Assim como somar 10h da manhã com 22h34 da novela não faz sentido, não faz sentido somar a Praça Portugal com o Cineteatro São Luiz.

### Então, qual a questão a ser respondida?

Para mim, parece que essa reação não ajuda muito os novatos (o @MeAjudaSilvio tá com 186 de reputação da hora que escrevo, então ele não deve ter tido grandes participações aqui no site; na real, ele só está aqui a 2 meses e uma semana ativamente perguntando/respondendo). Eu também me considero um novato, com apenas 4 meses de ativa participação, mas eu tenho problemas com pontuação e comunidade, quero me encaixar da maneira mais rápida e suave e ter o máximo de pontos possível, daí eu ter um tanto mais de participação no site.

Uma reação que eu creio ser mais razoável seria, na resposta, sugerir que o conceito real/necessário era o de intervalo de tempo/TimeSpan e trabalhar em cima disso. Pode parecer achismo sobre a pergunta, mas a intencionalidade de um texto é colocada muitas vezes de maneira não consciente e sua detecção é dependente do sujeito leitor. Então, achismos na resposta devem ser usados, para que a comunicação flua, mas deve vir junto de uma premissa interpretativa.

Algo vindo do achismo interpretativo foi [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208719/64969). Tl;dr: AP queria uma pilha de lista ligada e operações no final dela. Minha premissa achista: AP queria tratar uma pilha como um tipo abstrato de dado, independente de como essa dado estivesse guardado internamente. Mostrei a ele duas alternativas: uma removendo do final (como ele havia pedido), mas usando vetor; e outra removendo do começo, mas usando lista (como estava o código dele).

Outro ponto de imprecisão na hora de se fazer uma questão eu vi [nesta da Nadine M.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92516/64969). A pergunta é pequena, ela fala da problemática mas... melhor usar as palavras dela (ênfase minha):

> Porém o programa **dá** ao executar a ordenação ou não a executa direito

Gente, o quê ele dá? Bug? Resultado errado? Falha de segmentação? Café? Sinceramente, não temos como saber. Na revisão 3 ela explicitamente tira a palavra **erro** (que existia desde os primórdios da pergunta) e coloca **ao executar a ordenação ou não a executa direito**, mas isso foi proposital?, ou ela removeu demais?, ou ela esqueceu o complemento verbal diferente de **erro** que ela iria colocar ali?

Sinceramente, isso não fazia muita diferença, visto que o problema raiz dela poderia ser sanado sem precisar tomar conhecimento do problema do fim do ramo. Então por achismo cri que resolver a ordenação em uma lista ligada fosse atendê-la, por achismo ignorei o código que ela postou e foquei no problema original, não em catar erro, não em tentar fazer lógica de um algoritmo que poderia fazer tanto sentido como somar uma baleia azul à hora 10h47 da manhã.

Outro exemplo de achismos que serviram para construir a resposta: a pequena disputa entre [a resposta do Leo Caracciolo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193138/64969) e [a minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193061/64969). (No final, fiquei com um downvote, mas valeu a pena, ainda mais na minha primeira semana de participação aqui). Sobre informações incompletas e achismos bem posicionados e concorrência entre as respostas e troca de comentários, com a participação especial do AP, evoluímos até respostas satisfatórias (a minha tem downvote, mas tenho orgulho dela).

Às vezes, pelo desconhecimento técnico do assunto, pode acontecer de nem o AP saber qual a sua dúvida exata, mas sabe qual sua dificuldade aproximada.

### Conclusão

Devemos fechar questões por pedantismo formal?, para que ela seja reaberta quando o AP conseguir uma escrita de maneira menos ambígua?

Ou devemos assumir que a comunicação humana é falha e, sobre os traços de intencionalidade da pergunta, propor respostas parciais sobre premissas mais ou menos claras e interagir até que o AP consiga obter a resposta?

Comment: Gostei muito da sua resposta, e acho que poderia ser incluída em algum tipo de pergunta aqui meta sobre "devemos fechar perguntas prematuramente?", ou algo parecido.

Comment: Não discordo do que você disse, mas apenas queria chamar atenção para o fato real da pergunta. Meu ponto inicial não é o motivo do fechamento da pergunta, como eu mesmo falo na pergunta. O ponto da minha pergunta é o fato de um moderador fechar uma pergunta onde a mesma foi reaberta por *5 usuários* do site e fechada, novamente, pelo moderador. O ponto real foi a questão do moderador passar por cima de 5 usuários (com o decorrer da pergunta esse número subiu) e mesmo assim achar que está correto. Ou, caso esteja realmente, eu estou muito equivocado  :p

Comment: Temos de assumir que a comunidade SO funciona com uma coletânea de [BDFL](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6064/pergunta-fechada-corretamente-ou-uso-excessivo-de-poder/6065#comment23211_6065). Isso implica alguém que vai tomar as rédeas e acabou o assunto. Mas também devemos levar em consideração qual a intenção de tal comportamento. O comportamento do Bigown às vezes me faz pensar que ele é do tipo mais formal possível, daí isso remove a possibilidade de acrescer à comunidade sobre conhecimento parcial do causo.

Comment: Falo isso que ele já encerrou alguns debates comigo sem ter tirado a minha dúvida. Lembro duma discussão sobre banco de dados que eu não enxerguei o lado dele por muito tempo, e sinceramente não senti nele esforço em tentar me ajudar com isso. Foi uma discussão de laranjas com alfaces, mas para mim era tudo planta, não distinguia entre elas. Esse comportamento faz parte do Bigown, para o mal e para o bem. Em uma sidenote, depois de muito esforço e treleituras (releitura é pouco), consegui entender o ponto e, indagado sobre o ponto, ele confirmou-me que era aquilo mesmo

Comment: Eu não nego isso, tanto que falo que o primeiro fechamento eu achei correto. Porém, o segundo já existia comentários do AP e informações mais que suficiente para responder a pergunta. Sem falar que segundo [o próprio comentário dele](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6064/pergunta-fechada-corretamente-ou-uso-excessivo-de-poder/6068#comment23214_6065) ele recebeu uma sinalização no post, o que acho que está contra a "imparcialidade da questão".

Comment: Ressalto também que na [outra questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5965/20615) que ele mesmo mencionou, ele veio ao meta perguntar sobre a pergunta, antes de usar os poderes para reabrir, e que foi fechada pela fila de análise. Se ele acha que uma pergunta deve ser aberta e vem ao meta perguntar, pq não faz isso também para uma que foi fechada? 
Nota: não estou marcando o bigown em meus comentários pq ele está participando ativamente deste post, e não consigo marcar o mesmo em sua resposta, pois ele não comentou nesse post.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado De fato a resposta ficou meio fora porque pra mim a pergunta aqui era pra reclamar da minha ação e não discutir a pergunta. De fato eu prezo pela informação correta do que está sendo postado. Qdo fui eleito as pessoas já sabiam disto, sabiam que eu não gosto de peguntas mal elaboradas. Qdo as pessoas votam estão escolhendo que uma pessoa possa escolher o que fazer mesmo que 5 ou mais pessoas queiram outra coisa. Depois de toda eleição o eleito começa ser questionado logo depois. Isso ocorre fora da internet e ocorre nos outros sites da rede.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O que mais têm é acusação de que o moderador está sendo ditador. O moderador recebeu votos para fazer isto. Ele recebeu a confiança da comunidade. O moderador não vai acertar sempre. O moderador vai desagradar alguém sempre. Eu não comentarei o *sidenote* porque ´*off-topic*  já vi que não adianta. Na verdade provavelmente não responderei mais est tipo de coisa, já que é pra ser considerado ditador (não estou reclamando do BDFL, isso chega ser elogio), nem que você disse isso, então é melhor parar de ficar tentando debater. Como já haviam me alertado, não chega a lugar algum.

Comment: @bigown acho que não deixei meu ponto visível. Pode ter sido o sono ou o cansaço de empurrar um carro automático no meio da favela (shit happens). Vou tentar deixar o meu ponto principal mais evidente para os futuros leitores, que seriam as duas perguntas da conclusão

Comment: @bigown ser acusado de ditador é ônus do ofício. Sei como é, eu sou avaliador de códigos onde trabalho e boa parte das implementações eu barro. Pessoal fica com a maior raiva de mim, mas fazer o quê se está ruim?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado nem reclamo disso. Aprendi a lição que já haviam me falado, agora aprendi na prática. Essas discussões não levam a nada. A discussão produtiva que poderia ser feita não era o interesse aqui. Justamente eu acho esses pontos meio fora do contexto aqui. Não que não seja um bom assunto. Na pergunta que eu cito logo no início da minha resposta foi fechada por pedantismo. Teve outra que queriam fechar, acho que era sobre memória consumida pelo VS, idem. Esse assunto daria um bom debate. Não sei se seria produtivo, mas talvez chegasse a uma conclusão.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendo que o recurso que permite um membro de alta pontuação fechar com um único voto é útil na maioria dos casos mas muitas vezes testemunho essa situação onde não parece ser correta, onde o voto de um passa por cima de vários outros contrários. Isso fere o princípio de comunidade.

Existe uma comunidade justamente para que tenha uma diversidade de opiniões, pontos de vista, etc. Um moderador não é um superior, é um servidor. O respeito deve ser mútuo.

No geral, eu discordo da permissão de apenas um voto para fechar ou decidir algo pois a pessoa pode estar interpretando erroneamente um assunto e isso tem se mostrado recorrente. Acredito que tudo deve ser mais transparente e aberto a decisão da comunidade.

Conceder poder de decisão a uma pessoa é um tanto perigoso pois todos cometemos erros e propicia manipulação intencional.

Há alguns meses vi, se não me engano, o próprio bigown pedir aqui no meta que concedesse permissões de fechamento com apenas um voto para membros com uma determinada reputação (muitos pontos). E isso foi concedido quase que de imediato sem ser discutido. Na época preferi não comentar nada mas não vi com bons olhos. Não lembro como buscar aqui no meta mas deve estar aí em algum lugar. Imagine isso como se o presidente do país tivesse tal poder sem passar por filtros. É bem semelhante.

Por outro lado, também não acho que precisa alardear. Existe a opção de votar para reabrir. Então basta pedir para reabrir. Claro que se for insistentemente votado contra reabertura, então é um caso a parte a se discutir.

Saliento que **não se trata de crítica a pessoa**, mas ao gerenciamento das normas. Isso é uma crítica administrativa que deve ser revisada como propuseram nos comentários. Acredito não ser culpa de ninguém e tampouco haver atitudes má intencionadas. Apenas acontece naturalmente.

Não disponho de tempo para propor soluções além de comentar o óbvio acima. No entanto, apoio revisões e reformas e "cobrar" maior comprometimento de outros moderadores. Vejo ativamente uns 3 ou 4.

Afinal, se aceitaram a responsabilidade devem cumprir com a sua função mesmo que todos aqui sejam voluntários. Se há moderadores sem tempo ou disposição, então deve haver uma renovação.

Pesquisando, encontrei uma discussão antiga, não diretamente relacionada: [Estamos vivenciando uma experiência meritocrática?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1825) e existem diversos outros desse tipo. Não consigo encontrar a que mencionei. Pode ter sido excluída. Isso é também um problema pois diretrizes foram modificadas e sequer temos uma documentação sobre o que foi mudado e como isso se sucedeu. Ou seja, é obscuro, desorganizado, propício a atos inadequados (corrupção).

## Sobre a pergunta específica que foi o estopim dessa discussão

Não li as versões anteriores, mas a atual não me pareceu apresentar motivos para fechamento: [Soma, subtração, conversão de horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210468)

Nos comentários, o bigown "ataca" a resposta do randrade afirmando com veemência que está errada. Mas temos ali 10 votos positivos e aceitação do AP.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não queria colocar lenha na fogueira mas pessoalmente já tive uma situação de discórdia com ele (bigown) nessa questão: [Como bloquear adblock?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123884). Na resposta que postei, ele também colocou opinião pessoal afirmando estar errado. Eu fui veementemente contra e pedi diversas vezes para que outros moderadores analisassem e nada foi feito por semanas. Nessa época ele não era moderador mas devido a alta pontuação sempre exerceu influência em decisões. Na época não entendi a falta de ação de outros moderadores que pareciam ignorar ou protegê-lo. Deixaram a coisa do jeito que estava, completamente errada. Por fim, após um tempo voltei a insistir e removeram os comentários absurdos que ali existiam.

É muito comum algumas pessoas comentarem ou responderem de um jeito tendencioso, querendo mudar o modelo de negócios alheio e isso eu acho **invasivo e errôneo**. Não devemos querer mudar o modelo de negócios alheio até porque não o conhecemos, por isso é alheio. O foco deve estar na solução técnica. Ali você vê respostas dizendo que o AP deve desistir de ganhar dinheiro com banners mas, como que a pessoa responde dessa forma sem conhecer qual a finalidade do uso, a qual sequer foi comentada? Por isso a minha resposta foi aceita e mais votada.

Se o AP quer uma solução para fazer algo estúpido ou algo não muito usual, "FOD@-se". Não é problema nosso. Ele só quer uma solução objetiva. Muitas vezes, um programador é forçado a fazer coisas que não concorda. Existe um superior que manda fazer X mesmo sabendo que o caminho não é muito adequado, mas como subordinado, o programador deve cumprir com aquilo.

Isso é assunto paralelo ao foco do AP (Randrade), mas achei pertinente e oportuno ressaltar até como uma pequena amostra de como isso é recorrente.

Como isso tudo é um assunto um pouco delicado, precisei ler e reler o que estou postando e isso tomou muito do meu tempo. Pelo menos 70 minutos aqui para escrever e revisar. Se fiz alguma ofensa, por favor, não foi a intenção. Tentei resumir o máximo possível e manter uma polidez e imparcialidade dentro do tempo que nem tenho disponível no momento. Apenas achei a situação injusta e achei que é meu dever opinar. Contudo, se o bigown provar, como já pediram, que as respostas da questão [123884](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123884) são erradas, posso mudar de opinião. Não sou expert em C# para afirmar que podem estar erradas.

Comment: Concordar ou não com o fechamento da pergunta é uma coisa, por em causa a existência da prerrogativa que o moderador tem com o seu voto passar por cima de vários outros contrários é outra. Essa prerrogativa é uma das que distingue, em termos de moderação, um moderador de um usuário normal e faz todo o sentido em existir. Em nada ela "fere o princípio de comunidade".