# Sem experiência fala ou se cala?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Se um usuário que começou a pouco tempo e não tem certezas de suas respostas, ele deve se calar diante a algumas perguntas? Ou deve falar de igual forma, podendo responder a pergunta, mas também podendo falar besteira.

> Neste caso, eu sou um desses usuários.

Comment: Eu diria que depende dos casos. Em perguntas sobre código podes testar antes de fazer a resposta para verificar se funciona, garantindo assim que pelo menos responde à pergunta, e ai sim podes responder. Depois os restantes utilizadores vão votar na sua resposta conforma seja boa ou má. Já se for uma pergunta mais no âmbito de pergunta canónica só vale a pena responde se você souber a resposta, opinar sem estar baseado em nada não é resposta. Resumindo, **eu acho** que deve-se responder sempre na base de dar uma resposta concreta que pelo menos funcione, e deixar o **«achismos»** de fora.

Comment: Eu discorro sobre isso em outro [tópico no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6068/64969). Na minha opinião formatada, creio que achismos (da interpretação do problema do AP) bem intencionados e bem direcionados podem ser positivos. Se sua resposta estiver errada, não tem muito problema, você receberá votos negativos ou comentários explicando porque a resposta está absurda (já fiz isso, mas eu achava na época minha resposta correta)

Comment: Ola, boa indagação rsrs.
Eu me calo, não quero parecer mais tolo que posso ser.

Answer (score 44):

Em geral eu diria para falar. Mas ficar atento ao *feedback*, mesmo que ele seja um negativo. Aí pode tentar arrumar o problema e aprender junto. Se não conseguir arrumar ou for muito complicado talvez seja até o caso de apagar o que postou. Mas nem precisa desistir logo de cara. Então você não pode se irritar com negativos, você sabe que provavelmente eles são merecidos, precisa reagir positivamente a isto.

Recomendo não exagerar. Não saia respondendo algo que não tem a menor noção do que está falando. Errar todo mundo erra, mas tentar fazer algo que você sabe que não tem conhecimento acaba sendo improdutivo para todos.

Inclusive porque se começar ter muitos negativos pode ser bloqueado de responder. E apagar piora a situação, é confirmação que não sabia como arrumar. O único jeito de se recuperar de um bloqueio desses é resolver os problemas no que já foi postado e esperar reversão dos negativos, o que costuma ser difícil porque muita gente vê negativo e nem lê, ou negativa mais, ou deixa como está. É
o que eu já falei, as pessoas votam porque outras pessoas já votaram.

Claro que tem casos que é mais fácil acertar. Ao contrário do Jorge B. eu tenho dúvidas que só testando resolve. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo. De resto concordo com ele.

Estamos aqui pra ajudar.

---

Legal alguns depoimentos colocados aqui. Pena que só os que tem atitude positiva aparecem por aqui. Eu até acho que o sistema deve ajudar nisso, mas não é com a gente, tudo o que é sugerido esbarra na filosofia que o sistema deve interagir pouco com o usuário, que deve até mesmo tentar esconder coisas negativas (empurrar pra baixo do tapete). O sistema deveria servir de incentivador, de explicador do porque o usuário não está se dando mal. Mostrar o caminho. Não pode esperar que outros usuários o façam, pode dar sorte de ocorrer, ou pode não dar. Feito do jeito certo o resultado pode ser melhor. Inclusive porque vejo que um dos maiores problemas dos usuários não é nem de programação, é de atitude.

Comment: Falando em apagar a resposta, se você esperar pelo menos três negativos, ainda ganha uma medalha =D

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a medalha que eu mais odeio :) É quase um incentivo a fazer coisa errada

Comment: @bigown eu não sei se temos o mesmo algoritmo do SOen, mas lá se tiveres muitas respostas más acabas por ficar bloqueado.

Comment: @bigown hahaha! Se não fosse por essa medalha, eu teria deixado aquela péssima resposta minha sobre exceção no C#, manter um _hall of shame_ pessoal

Comment: Já agora eu não disse que estava certo se funcionasse, mas que pelo menos respondia à pergunta. São coisas diferentes ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. verdade, tinha esquecido disto, editei. Obrigado.

Comment: @JorgeB. penso eu que o bloqueio que se refere seja o "penalidade"?

Comment: *"Mas ficar atento ao feedback, mesmo que ele seja um negativo"* resumindo, pode até ficar no *achismo*, mas seja receptivo ao receber criticas de outros usuários, mesmo que negativa. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [Por que as respostas não são mais aceitas da minha conta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: @JorgeB. sim foi justamente o que pensei, existe sim no SOpt, inclusive lembro de pelo menos um caso.

Comment: *"Então você **não pode se irritar com negativos**, você sabe que provavelmente eles são merecidos, precisa reagir positivamente a isto."* - Precisa de mais ênfase!

Answer (score 36):

Falando um pouco da minha experiência...

Eu tenho a minha conta registrada no Stack Overflow em Português faz 3 anos e 3 meses, conforme o sistema mesmo diz, mas até o dia 24 de janeiro deste ano, 2017, eu possuía 50 pontos de reputação. Isso porquê quando eu criei a conta eu não me sentia preparado para participar ativamente de forma construtiva. Muitas vezes eu achava que tinha conhecimento sobre o assunto abordado em uma pergunta e quando via a resposta de algum usuário mais experiente, parecia que fugia completamente daquilo eu havia imaginado. O que mudou nesse dia foi que eu acessei o site com uma nova mentalidade: **tentar**. Estava pensando comigo: eu estudo programação de forma autodidata desde meu primeiro computador, quando eu tinha apenas 10 anos de idade, já trabalhei profissionalmente na área de web development, não é possível que eu não saiba responder com autoridade alguma pergunta. Então assim o fiz. Apareceu uma pergunta de Python que eu sabia fazer funcionar e respondi. Tive um *feedback* bom em relação ao que eu esperava e a resposta foi aceita, mesmo não sendo a resposta mais completa. Isso me animou bastante e eu parti para a segunda pergunta, agora de PHP e para minha surpresa, o *feedback* também foi muito positivo. Para quem tinha apenas 50 pontos de reputação, ganhar 287 no primeiro dia foi surpreendente, pelo menos para mim. Isso me incentivou muito em participar mais ativamente e deu no que deu.

Dito isso, respondendo a pergunta, eu concordo com o bigown na questão de tentar. Funcionou comigo e provavelmente funcionará com outros usuários. Não digo todos, pois sempre há usuários que não sabem receber *feedback*. No meu caso foi bem tranquilo, pois o *feedback* que recebi foi positivo, mas ser negativo não deverá ser um motivo para desistir. Mas não tente exaustivamente. Por vezes aparece usuários novos que respondem todas as perguntas com respostas de 3 a 4 linhas, sem dizer nada, com qualidade baixa e incompleta. Não é esse tipo de tentar. Se você for novo na computação, isto é, não possui autoridade/experiência para responder as maiorias das respostas que vê, comece participando mais pelos comentários. Você já possui reputação para isso, então ao invés de colocar respostas que não possui completa certeza ou incompletas, você pode comentar colocando a sua sugestão de solução. Quando a pergunta receber respostas de qualidade, compare aquilo que você comentou com as respostas; se for semelhante, você começará a ganhar confiança sobre o assunto, mas, principalmente, se for diferente, comente na própria resposta pedindo o porquê daquela solução ser melhor que a sua do comentário. Com isso você aprenderá mais a cada participação. Pode acontecer de até a resposta dada por um usuário mais experiente não ser melhor que a sua e ele te encorajar a postar sua resposta.

Mas, em qualquer caso, sempre que for responder, priorize a qualidade. Geralmente o autor da pergunta adiciona o código que tentou fazer, então se for responder com uma outra solução, busque explicar qual era o erro no código do autor. Apenas postar um código que funciona diferente do autor é basicamente incentivá-lo a copiar e colar. Por vezes o próprio autor irá atrás de entender o seu código, não cabe a nós julgar isso de fato, mas a comunidade, em si, se beneficia muito mais quando você compara as duas soluções do que quando você sobrepõem uma com outra. Se sua solução utiliza funções nativas da linguagem, busque referenciar a página da documentação oficial das mesmas para que se algum usuário desconhecer aquela função ele possuir material de leitura. Se for uma função pouco conhecida, as vezes é interessante descrever seu funcionamento e uso na própria resposta. Além disso, busque entender o grau de conhecimento do autor da pergunta. Se você perceber que é um usuário novo na programação, busque explicar todos os detalhes da sua resposta, descrevendo a lógica desenvolvida, porquê ela foi implementada daquela forma, porquê ela funciona daquela maneira, etc. Se for um usuário experiente, busque abordar todos os detalhes que envolvem o contexto da pergunta, pois sendo um usuário experiente, provavelmente ele já possuirá um conhecimento prévio sobre o assunto, então você não precisará explicar tudo passo a passo, mas será interessante abordar todos os detalhes do problema e da solução, pois assim haverá uma discussão bem saudável e construtiva para a comunidade.

Como eu comentei, isso o que eu disse é baseado na minha experiência e é o que eu busco fazer todos os dias desde que comecei a participar ativamente. Acredito que vem dado certo desde então.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Concordo e sobrescrevo.

Answer (score 25):

> Se um usuário que começou a pouco tempo e não tem certezas de suas respostas(...)

Não existe correlação entre o tempo de experiência no Stack Overflow com a quantidade de experiência ou grau de habilidade da pessoa. Você duvidaria de uma resposta do Mark Zuckerberg em uma pergunta sobre API do Facebook se ele aparecesse aqui com um único ponto de reputação?

> (...)Ele deve se calar diante a algumas perguntas?(...)

Alguns usuários, principalmente novatos, vêem pontuações e medalhas dos usuários mais experientes e acabam por ter uma impressão de que as coisas por aqui funcionam assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é uma impressão errada. Uma resposta correta é uma resposta correta independente da sua pontuação ou histórico. Assim como uma resposta errada é uma resposta errada independente das suas credenciais.

Também podemos dizer que uma resposta não é boa por ter vindo de uma pessoa com alta pontuação, mas sim que a pessoa tem alta pontuação porque tem o costume de dar boas respostas.

E lembre-se: todo mundo começa com um único ponto. Quem tem muitos pontos hoje é justamente por não ter ficado calado :)

> (...)Ou deve falar de igual forma, podendo responder a pergunta, mas também podendo falar besteira.

Um grande arquiteto e poeta cearense compôs uma canção que responde de forma pungente a esse questionamento:

> E sendo eu um grande entendido no assunto
>   Eu paro e vejo como tem gente besta no mundo
>   Por outro lado, eu fiz um estudo
>   E sei que é melhor falar besteira
>   Do que ser mudo
>
> (trecho de *A besteira é a base da sabedoria*, de Marcondes Falcão Maia)

Comment: hahaha você conseguiu fazer jus ao dito: *"Uma foto vale mais que 1000 palavras"*

Comment: Há controvérsias, 1,93m não é tão grande quanto parece :)

Comment: Ótima foto. Diz muita coisa....

Comment: _E lembre-se: todo mundo começa com um único ponto. Quem tem muitos pontos hoje é justamente por não ter ficado calado_: Boa! :-D

Answer (score 24):

Vou começar dizendo, que já vi até usuário veterano ou com pontuação alta respondendo besteiras, posso até citar um exemplo de usuário, mesmo na época ele já tendo cerca 20k ~ 40k, o nome deste tolo é:

> [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento)

Sim, **sou eu**, e talvez você encontre outros, não é que eu fiquei fazendo uso de **«achismos»**, de certa forma eu acreditava estar correto, mas nem vou entrar em detalhes, vou só dizer o que eu *«acho»* que qualquer usuário deve fazer:

- Se quer **«chutar»** uma resposta ao menos pesquise em outros sites sobre o assunto. Fazendo isto, tua chances de falhar diminuem em muito.
- Se começar a receber uma série de downvotes devido a uma resposta sua, não presuma que é um ataque pessoal, isto apenas deve indicar que você respondeu algo errado e é uma ótima oportunidade para aprender sobre o assunto e melhorar a resposta.
- Agora vem a parte que muito usuário que esta começando **falha**, ontem mesmo 2 usuários, ambos com média de 1k, em perguntas diferentes responderam coisas bem erradas, eu apenas comentei explicando e tentando apontar aonde eles falharam, ao invés deles receberem como critica construtiva eles simplesmente fizeram o pior, um me mandou *"parar de falar besteira"* e outro negativou minha postagem (uma delas era minha pergunta), felizmente consegui remediar e nos entendemos. O problema é este, mesmo uma critica negativa pode ser útil, basta saber tirar proveito dela, mesmo que pareça grosseira.

**Então para resumir,** você deve saber receber uma critica e fazer uma pesquisa prévia antes de responder a algo.

Comment: Olha ai os direitos de autor de **«achismos»** :P

Comment: Sempre quando não tenho certeza da resposta, posto na parte dos comentários. Tipo "Você já testou isso aqui....". Algumas vezes já recebi respostas corretas até por comentários.

Comment: "responderam coisas bem erradas, eu apenas comentei explicando e tentando apontar aonde eles falharam, ao invés deles receberem como critica construtiva eles simplesmente fizeram o pior, um me mandou "parar de falar besteira" e outro negativou minha postagem" não tive a mesma sorte :)

Comment: @bigown é conheço um pouco da sua historia e sofrimento no site

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou falando até especificamente do de ontem. Na verdade eu acho que a maioria das pessoas não sabem de todo rolo que me meto porque a maioria se resolve, como resolveu esse caso pra você, o problema é sempre quando a pessoa não quer resolver. Paciência.

Comment: @bigown sim, eu estava pensando justamente nisto, depois que li sua resposta e um certo comentário passei a entender o problema daquilo, eu estava até pensando em responder lá (no meta mesmo), mas como vc disse que iria tentar criar algo "canônico" eu preferi esperar. Paciência :/

Comment: Quando vi o começo da resposta pensei: **isso vai dar uma m¨rda**, fui logo ver o autor da resposta. Boa resposta!

Comment: @AndréFilipe uma autocritica e até aceitar critica dos outros, desde que bem fundamentadas sempre podem tornar a comunidade e a nós mesmos melhor :)

Comment: Concerteza @GuilhermeNascimento, acredito que um dos fatores que impulsionam o aprendizado é realizar a autocritica e aceitar todas as críticas positivas e negativas como criticas construtoras!

Answer (score 13):

Não ia responder nada e os colegas já mostraram bem que é interessante falar sim, desde que você tenha alguma convicção de que sabe minimamente do que está dizendo, mas, resolvi falar um pouco sobre a minha breve história por aqui também, depois de ler a mensagem do [Anderson](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/).

Por muito tempo eu só "consumi" conteúdo do SO<sup>EN</sup>, sem participar ativamente, mas quando precisei fazer minha primeira pergunta me inscrevi e depois de um tempo resolvi começar a tentar participar do SO<sup>EN</sup>, mas, o começo foi bem difícil porque lá é complicado responder algo, tem gente demais e é tudo muito dinâmico, se você demora um pouco, em alguns segundos já tem 3 respostas e você nem começou a escrever a sua, e aí tem uma parte frustrante da experiência de iniciante no StackOverflow que é o fato de você não poder participar com comentários até atingir 50 pontos, e foi difícil chegar lá, então, me sentia meio inútil no começo.

Aí descobri o SO<sup>PT</sup> e comecei a tentar participar aqui também. Mas, diferente do Anderson (e por isso resolvi responder também), o meu começo aqui também foi bem difícil. Eu respondi algumas perguntas sobre um assunto que estava iniciando na época (eSocial), e que eu já tinha escrito algumas coisas em um site "meu", então, dei respostas sucintas e postei o link do que tinha escrito externamente para mais detalhes, só que comecei a receber votos negativos, e os poucos pontos suados que eu já tinha foram embora, praticamente voltei à estaca zero (ou pontuação 1).

Aquilo me deixou bem chateado e desmotivado e eu pensei em simplesmente desistir do SO<sup>PT</sup>, deixar quieto, parar de participar. Mas ao invés disso, eu acabei me motivando a mostrar que eu sabia do que estava falando e melhorei as respostas (obrigado ao [Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/) por ser gente boa e compreensivo na época), colocando tudo que eu já tinha escrito no link externo e mais um pouco, e fiquei feliz com o resultado e agradeci pelos pontos negativos, porque isso fez com que eu melhorasse muito a minha resposta inicial.

E aí eu percebi que o pessoal aqui simplesmente parece ser muito mais crítico do que o pessoal da versão de língua inglesa, e aqui parece que preferem grandes respostas detalhadas. Se você notar, aqui as respostas mais bem votadas normalmente são textos enormes, enquanto que no SO<sup>EN</sup>, mesmo se você vir as respostas do [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/), que é simplesmente o cara com a maior reputação do StackOverflow, com mais de um milhão de pontos, as respostas em geral são mais sucintas. Entretanto, isso é questão de cultura de cada comunidade, então tem que se adaptar ao meio.

Mas também não quer dizer que respostas sucintas não sejam válidas. Se forem dadas com certa propriedade e responderem a pergunta, na minha opinião está valendo. Aliás, sou a favor de ter uma versão sucinta da resposta mesmo que já exista uma versão mega detalhada, porque às vezes você só precisa de uma resposta rápida e não terá tempo para ler o mega texto naquele momento. Não estou criticando os textos grandes, acho legal também ter respostas super completas! E quem sou eu, com uma resposta desse tamanho, para criticar textos grandes, não é mesmo? :-)

Enfim, resumindo, fale sempre que souber do que está falando e não desista fácil com as adversidades que vêm no processo, porque elas normalmente contribuem para o seu crescimento (o que é outro motivo para não se calar, e tentar)!

Comment: Depois de responder que percebi que tanto a pergunta quanto as respostas são de mais de um ano atrás... (tapa na testa!) O Eco-Faria Netto postou um comentário na pergunta e trouxe ela pro topo da *timeline* e achei que era de hoje, rs... Foi mal. Provavelmente sou eu o *noob* ali da foto :-p

Answer (score 8):

Realmente ficamos sempre com um pé atrás do que as pessoas vão pensar de nossas respostas, mas a única forma de ficar bom é tentando, se você nunca tentar irá ficar com 1 de reputação para sempre.

Tenha em mente, que mesmo quando você é negativado aquilo serve de aprendizado para você. Basta reler a sua pergunta e provavelmente irá notar o porquê de ter acontecido isso. Dificilmente nessa plataforma somos negativados atoa, principalmente porque as respostas são quase sempre objetivas e não se baseiam em opiniões pessoais, então em boa parte dos casos você realmente está certo ou errado, as vezes mesmo certo será negativado por ter ferido alguma regra da comunidade, mas aos poucos você vai pegando, para isso precisa arriscar.

Só para finalizar, é muito satisfatório quando a sua resposta ajuda o próximo, é um sentimento de dever cumprido, vale a pena arriscar!

Comment: Por mais usuários que vejam o negativo como você, é o que precisamos aqui, pois, pra maioria atual, é quase uma ofensa. O ideal e que o negativo venha junto com um comentário alertando do que pode ser problemático no post, mas como disse, as pessoas aqui levam o negativo tao a serio q fazendo isso, vc acaba sendo perseguido. No mais, concordo contigo, é muito bom ver que algo que você compartilhou serviu para outra pessoa :)

Comment: Verdade, acho que o negativo tem que vir sempre com alguma indicação do porquê, caso contrário a pessoa não aprende, e é muito frustrante pra quem é negativado, quando você acha que fez tudo certo e alguém te negativa e você não faz ideia do motivo.

Comment: @PedroGaspar Essa questão de "negativo tem que ter comentário" já foi muito discutida em vários sites da rede, e no fim a conclusão ("oficial", por enquanto) é que deixar como está tem mais prós do que contras: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437

Comment: @PedroGaspar Eu mesmo já percebi que se vc comentar, alguns acham que foi vc que negativou e se irritam. Como nunca dá pra saber se o usuário vai reagir bem ao comentário/voto, a maioria acaba optando por não comentar mesmo...

Comment: Caro Eduardo, vou repetir o que eu disse em minha resposta: [Se quer «chutar» uma resposta ao menos pesquise em outros sites sobre o assunto. Fazendo isto, tua chances de falhar diminuem em muito.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6074/3635)... Então arriscar não é o caminho correto, ao menos não sozinho, arrisque, mas pesquisem antes, tem muitas fontes de info razoaveis. O problema das pessoas é o desespero para ganhar upvotes, ai é que esta o problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo com o que você disse, mas mesmo pesquisando muitas vezes estamos 'arriscando', pois nosso conhecimento está sendo colocado a prova, existe o medo do desconhecido, o medo de ser rejeitado, assim dizendo, tentei colocar nesse sentido, mas acho que eu deveria ter desenvolvido mais essa parte na resposta, relendo aqui não ficou muito claro. Ressaltando o que você disse, realmente está correto e é o que devemos fazer quando temos dúvida em alguma resposta.

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro melhor arriscar com alguma fonte externa do arriscar teorias inventadas na hora, aliais tem uma meia duzia de usuários aqui no site que fazem isso, principalmente em perguntas sobre regex, que respondem de forma extremamente incorreta, algo que já até desisti de debater com eles, ainda sim buscar fontes, documentações e até respostas em sites primos, como SOen é melhor que sair chutando e arriscando ;)

Comment: Vou te fazer uma confissão que talvez te tranquilize e te motive. Minhas ultimas 10 respostas no site, 9 eu pesquisei porque nao tinha muito noção de como responder e isso me fez não só achar a solucão pro OP mas tb aprender como fazer aquilo p/ poder explicar. É uma troca mútua, pois voce aprende para poder responder, e o autor aprende com sua resposta :)

Comment: Eduardo, acrescentando mais um "causo" aqui: há uns meses atrás eu fui corrigido pelo @GuilhermeNascimento (justamente em uma resposta que eu usava regex), mas em vez de me ofender (como acontece com muita gente aqui), isso me motivou a estudar regex mais a fundo, e vi que ainda tinha **muita** coisa pra aprender. Espero ter melhorado (inclusive, Guilherme, se eu ainda estiver errando, pode falar!), e esse é um motivo pra continuar respondendo perguntas - é como o Articuno disse, muita coisa eu aprendo enquanto estou escrevendo a resposta, e sempre há algo a mais para aprender

Comment: **PARABÉNS** @hkotsubo fico muito feliz pela sua maneira de pensar e pela sua evolução!

Comment: @ArticunoL, que bom saber que não sou o único! Eu também faço muito isso, algumas respostas eu sei mesmo, mas pesquiso um pouco para citar referências, e acabo aprendendo mais do que sabia, algumas eu tenho uma noção da resposta mas não muito, e pesquiso para me certificar e responder melhor, e aprendo também no processo, mas algumas eu não sei mesmo e pesquiso e acabo aprendendo tudo para responder, e isso é muito legal!

Answer (score 5):

Quando eu vejo uma pergunta e tenho alguma noção de uma possível solução mas não tenho certeza, tento procurar fontes e deixar a recomendação e links no comentário da pergunta, sem formular uma resposta sem muito embasamento.

Answer (score 0):

Em geral, acredito que a fala seja positiva, porém vejo em muitos casos como feedback apenas uma negativação, o que prejudica o usuário novato, o que seria de maior produtividade um comentário explicando o erro e ensinando, vejo os erros como oportunidades de aprendizagem, porem a negativação torna esta oportunidade apenas em uma punição cuja qual faz com que os novatos tenham medo de se expor.

Comment: Isso acontecia comigo no começo, tanto é que deletei minha conta de tanto *downvote* que tinha kk, mas resolvi me dedicar mais ao *SOpt*, durante um mês e ver no que dava :) perguntava sobre os downvotes e tentata entender onde errei :)

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente eu me calo, quando não domino bem um assunto, sendo que outro dia me surpreendi quando fiz uma pergunta. Para minha surpresa a minha pergunta ajudou muita gente.

Quando eu mesmo acabei achando a resposta e respondendo. De alguma forma mesmo não tendo muita experiência ajudei e fui ajudado.