# Qual o critério para dizer se uma pergunta é ampla demais?

Tags: debate

Abri uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342161/fazer-objeto-dom-acompanhar-o-mouse) e esta foi marcada como ampla demais por um dos moderadores.

> [image: Screeenshot da pergunta deletada]

No entanto não vejo nenhuma diferença com diversas perguntas feitas por esse mesmo moderador:

- [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)
- [As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar)
- [Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%C3%A9tico-para-o-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro)

Gostaria de saber qual o critério para dizer se a pergunta está ampla demais.

Comment: Acho que o critério é pessoal, mas a decisão é conjunta e só é definida após 5 analises concordantes. Eu particularmente espero que os autores das perguntas façam uma pesquisa mínima e demostrem isso na pergunta com argumentos, ou códigos e dúvidas mais específicas. Seria interessante demonstrar as formas como tentaram solucionar o problema, as fontes de suas pesquisas. E a definição clara do resultado que desejam obter.

Comment: Veja o comentário do Laércio Lopes na sua pergunta. Faltam elementos para entender de fato o que você quer. Releia e a sua pergunta e se coloque no lugar de alguém que não sabe de antemão o que você quer e veja se você entenderia a sua própria pergunta.

Comment: 1.) "Edita a pergunta colocando o HTML com o elemento que quer que acompanhe o ponteiro." Se eu não especifiquei é porque é irrelevante, pode ser um <span>, uma <image> qualquer elemento html.
2.) "Informe se quer que isso aconteça logo quando o usuário acessar a página ou depois de algum outro evento." Novamente, se não ta especifico é porque não é relevante.
3) "Dê mais detalhes, acredito que é uma pergunta válida." Ele reconhece que a pergunta é valida, só quer mais elementos pra ajudar a montar sua resposta, talvez outros usuarios nao precisem desses elementos

Comment: Ninguém falou que ela é inválida, só que não dá para responder na forma atual. O que você fez? Ignorou o que foi dito, e agora apagou a pergunta.

Comment: Esta não foi fechada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305160/101 e muito bem aceita. É uma pena que a pessoa que tem uma reclamação nunca reconhece o outro lado.

Comment: A sua pergunta e as perguntas linkadas são totalmente diferentes em múltiplos aspetos. O primeiro e mais gritante é o facto de a sua ser sobre como codificar uma solução especifica para um problema especifico numa linguagem especifica. As linkadas são mais perguntas conceptuais de como abordar determinado problema. Numa pergunta especifica como a sua falta muita informação para poder ter uma resposta aceitavel.

Comment: "Edita a pergunta colocando o HTML com o elemento que quer que acompanhe o ponteiro." - Não é irrelevante. O html pode mudar drasticamente a solução, seja utilizando tags ou até mesmo desenhando coisas com num canvas. "Informe se quer que isso aconteça logo quando o usuário acessar a página ou depois de algum outro evento." - Novamente não é irrelevante pois está a ser perguntado em que situação aquilo acontece. Se é sempre ou mediante algum evento. Isto também muda bastante a solução ao problema, dependendo do caso.

Comment: A pergunta foi apagada, algum usuário >= 10K poderia colocar um print por favor?

Comment: @hkotsubo feito. Considerando que ela é o objeto da postagem, não tem sentido preservar o limite dos 10k

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado!

Comment: Não se rebele com o site ou com o sistema dele, ou com pessoas. O SO é uma excelente oportunidade de vc crescer como profissional em vários aspectos, seja com erros ou com acertos. Eu aprendi mais com o SO nesses 2 anos de atividade do que em 10 trabalhando na área. Claro que em todo lugar vc vai achar que alguma coisa foi injusta, que há panelinhas etc., mas faça vista grossa pra isso e procure entender e fazer uma auto-crítica, e dar o seu melhor. Se achar que algo foi injusto à sua pessoa, reclame, mas a nível técnico, tente entender o motivo e tente consertar.

Comment: Realmente a sua pergunta foi digna de ser fechada pelo motivo especificado. Diariamente dezenas (talvez centenas) de perguntas são fechadas pelo mesmo motivo. Não vale a pena desperdiçar energia com isso. Se a pergunta foi fechada, analise-a e tente melhorá-la. Com certeza ela seria reaberta e teria muito valor no site como fonte de conhecimento para quem quiser fazer a mesma coisa. Eu mesmo já pensei em abandonar o site milhares de vezes, mas ainda bem que não o fiz, senão não teria aprendido muita coisa.

Comment: Fica aí, relaxe, acalme o ânimo, restaure o seu nick e vamos tocar juntos o site. Com certeza num futuro próximo vc verá que valeu a pena.

Answer (score 13):

Todas as perguntas citadas são conceituais, faz-se uma pergunta do que é aquilo e obtém uma resposta explicativa de algo que é mais ou menos **universal para todos** que precisam daquilo. Note também o texto está razoavelmente caprichado, mostra que houve um esforço em tornar a pergunta pertinente e que dê para responder. A sua, mesmo que não seja a real intenção, passa a ideia de que jogou alguma coisa qualquer sem pensar muito, sem o menor esforço e que uma solução. Isso acaba influenciando.

Sua pergunta é um pedido para **fazer algo** para o que **você** precisa, você não quer uma explicação de um conceito geral da computação, quer uma solução para um problema. Isto beira a nem estar no nosso escopo, pode ser confundido como fora de escopo por ser um pedido de "faz pra mim". Ainda assim considerei que não era bem isso que queria. Só que não tem informações para que qualquer solução seja certa ou todas podem estar erradas. Existem diversas formas de fazer isto, só você sabe qual é a adequada. E mesmo que alguém responda (e até tentaram) ela pode estar errada porque não tem informação suficiente. Ou pode acontecer pior, você achar que aquilo atendeu o que queria, mas nem ser, afinal se você não sabe como fazer, e até mesmo descrever o problema com detalhes, como saberá se é bom? Existe uma coisa chamada [Efeito Duning Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) onde a pessoa que não entende sobre o assunto assume que entende mesmo assim e acaba aceitando como certo algo que é errado, afinal ela não sabe avaliar, e este é um dos motivos de existir tantas *fake news*, até onde ninguém nem percebe (nossa área está cheia delas). E ninguém mais sabe se é bom ou não. Tudo está na sua cabeça.

Dá pra se questionar se a pergunta na verdade está não clara, mas ainda assim não está boa, a única forma de responder é te dar um código que a pessoa acha que pode te atender.

Como referência pode ler [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101). Mesmo não sendo uma batalha entre duas coisas, só dá para responder se for específico o suficiente, ter requisitos muito claros, completos, detalhados, ter todas restrições, ter um parâmetro do que é o resultado esperado. Tendo tudo isto não garante que a pergunta pode ser adequadamente respondida, mas já ajuda bem e pode salvar a pergunta.

O motivo do fechamento pode até ser errado (eu acho que precisamos afinar mais isso), mas a pergunta na forma atual não é boa para um site de perguntas e respostas. Se alguém achar que tem motivo melhor eu posso trocar.

E sempre é possível argumentar contra um fechamento ou pedir esclarecimentos como feito aqui. Se houver erro é possível corrigir.

Comment: Na verdade não é um pedido para fazer algo para mim e sim para ver abordagens diferenciadas de um mesmo problema.

Comment: `ver abordagens diferenciadas de um mesmo problema`. Agora ficou mais claro que é ampla mesmo, eu já tinha percebido que era algo assim. Quer várias abordagens, sem dar detalhe algum, e qualquer uma pode ser boa, poder ser a que você escolhe, ou qualquer uma pode ser a errada, vai depender do seu gosto, a pessoa que postar tem que dar sorte se era aquilo o que te agradaria. Sempre tem mais detalhes na central de ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: De qualquer forma, já removi a pergunta. Agradeço pela atenção, mas participar alguns meses do fórum deixa claro que todas as críticas que já ouvi sobre o SOpt ser uma panelinha fazem sentido. Se você tem uma reputação legal pode perguntar porque a banana é amarela. Do contrário, ficam inventando desculpa para limitar sua participação. Se não fosse essa postura tão errática, provavelmente muito mais gente se disporia a contribuir. Não acho que existe justificativa para fechar a pergunta sendo que existem diversas outras tão amplas quanto.

Comment: @JulianoNunes eu já vi muitas dessas críticas, quase todas elas vinham de pessoas que não se importavam com o site, apenas com a solução do seu problema do jeito que a pessoa quer. Ela quer fazer parte da panelinha, mas tem que ser do jeito dela, ela não quer se adaptar, ela quer impor, especialmente quando a pessoa pede ajuda, ela acha que as pessoas que dedicam seu tempo para ajudar devem servir a elas que estão procurando ajuda, elas não conseguem olhar o esforço que as pessoas que estão aqui fazem para ajudar sem ganhar nada. Em geral elas são ingratas e tendenciosas.

Comment: Lamento que você esteja embarcando nessa, mas sempre é possível tomar consciência. Você fez uma reclamação, mas não justificou ou argumentou, só disse que discorda, e que o problema não pode ser seu, só pode ser de todos os outros que estão aqui se dedicando. Não parece ser uma atitude que construa alguma melhoria, seja ela qual for. Lamento também que não consiga ver como sua pergunta é bastante claramente inferior às demais apresentadas e com uma conotação totalmente diferente.

Comment: Lamento mais uma vez que prefira o caminho "se não for do meu jeito eu não brinco e vou só criticar" e por isso prefira não tentar melhorar sua pergunta para uma forma que dê para responder. Quando tem coisa ruim de usuários de boa reputação "toma" do mesmo jeito (tem exemplos recentes, e o usuário reclama também). Só que estes usuários costumam cometer menos erros. Isso as pessoas não olham. Elas não querem perder tempo analisando como se faz uma pergunta legal, como pode melhorar, o que tem nas coisas bem aceitas que a dele não tem. Podemos explicar, ajudar, mas ñ podemos mudar a mente delas

Comment: @JulianoNunes, há 9 meses atrás eu tinha apenas 11 pontos de reputaçao, comecei a participar no site, e em um dia só perdi 8 pontos por votos negativos nas minhas respostas e fiquei com 3 pontos de reputação. No começo eu fiquei "p* da vida" e pensei em simplesmente desistir de participar do SO, mas dei a volta por cima e então decidi que ia melhorar as minhas respostas ([relato aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7421/86952)). Hoje continuo por aqui. A propósito, o SO [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/86952).

Comment: @PedroGaspar minha estória é parecida, no SOen, e olha tudo o que mudou pra mim. O SO é um microcosmo da sociedade (+/-). A gente aprende trabalhar em equipe, melhorar o que fazemos em tudo, não só na parte técnica, ver que erramos e como consertar, como construir, argumentar, liderar, ajudar, ver o outro lado, observar, aprender com os mais experientes, procurar soluções para o que queremos, ser resilientes com as inevitáveis frustrações, aceitar o outro, que nem tudo é como queremos, etc. Pessoas como você fazem o site crescer, as outras não irrelevantes, nem ajudam, nem atrapalham.

Comment: Eu tenho uma palestra que falo da mudança na minha vida por causa do Stack Overflow. O quanto me ajudou ser melhor profissional em tudo, o quanto foi difícil. Mas ele separa muito quem sabe fazer uma limonada com o limão. Uma pena que nem todos são assim. E pena que no Brasil (acho que em Portugal também) as empresas não observam isto. Fora o pessoa usa o SO pra ver se a pessoa tem potencial para ser bom profissional, inclusive olha o quanto a pessoa faz parte da solução e o quanto faz parte do problema. Eu poderia ser melhor, mas sou o que sou e tento melhorar.

Comment: Existe uma panelinha no SOpt de pessoas que se esforçam, capricham, seguem as regras, demonstram conhecimento, observam o comportamento dos outros e evoluem o seu próprio, que se preocupam com seu conteúdo e fazê-lo ser relevante para todos e não para só para si mesmo ou para quem perguntou, e que estão presentes com dedicação no site. Todos os anos (já são 5 deste site) temos novos membros na panelinha. Eles nunca pedem para entrar, eles chegam e entram, fazendo tudo isto que descrevi. Sua entrada nem é percebida, vai acontecendo. Esperamos você que está lendo na panelinha, já pode começar.