# Reconhecimento por buscar ajuda

Tags: debate

Às vezes eu entro em uma pergunta mesmo sem entender do tema. Acontece de eu conseguir buscar alguma ajuda internet afora e conseguir ajudar via comentários (não com a resposta).

Creio que mais pessoas fazem isso também, e gostaria de saber se existe algum reconhecimento por parte dos usuários quando percebem que o usuário está tentando ajudar mesmo não entendendo do assunto.

Da minha parte, quando não entendo do assunto e consigo alguma coisa, prefiro responder nos comentários em vez de realmente responder para não correr o risco de tomar negativação.

Comment: Que tipo de reconhecimento você se refere? Em questão de pontos dentro do sistema?

Comment: Eu acredito que não em questão de pontos, pois sendo as pontuações automáticas, acho muito difícil o sistema checar algo assim. Digo por parte dos usuários, de quem pergunta. Não para enaltecer o ego de quem está buscando ajudar sem conhecer, mas dos usuários em não criticar as tentativas de ajuda, e também incentivar outras pessoas a ajudarem mesmo não sendo a sua área de atuação, conforme o tempo de cada um, é claro. Talvez esse post seja uma forma de incentivar aqueles que tem um tempo disponível a ajudar em perguntas que não sejam de sua própria área de atuação.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Sem experiência fala ou se cala?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6070/sem-experi%c3%aancia-fala-ou-se-cala)

Comment: Dados os esclarecimentos, parece-me que a questão é duplicata da pergunta citada.

Comment: Anderson, como o tema da minha questão foi diferente do tema dessa que já existe, não percebi se já tinham sitado esse assunto. O que é melhor eu fazer? Excluir a pergunta ou deixar marcá-la como suplicada mesmo?

Comment: Se concorda que é duplicada, pode mantê-la como duplicada mesmo - isso ajudará inclusive no algoritmo de busca do sistema, pois da mesma maneira que você não encontrou a outra pergunta, outros usuários podem também não encontrar. Se acha que é uma discussão diferente, poderá manter sua pergunta aberta, mas neste caso recomendaria que buscasse ser mais claro na pergunta inclusive descrevendo o objetivo da mesma, pois ficou bastante obscuro o que você estava querendo com a pergunta.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7663/101