# O que deve ser fechado?

Tags: debate, fechamento

Ultimamente algumas pessoas, individualmente ou em grupo tem pedido para abrir perguntas que sempre foram consideradas como passíveis de serem fechadas por algum motivo. Eventualmente outras pessoas votaram para fechar junto comigo, algumas eu fechei sozinho, o que não dá para saber se ninguém quis fechar porque acham que deveria ficar aberta, ou se ficaram na dúvida, ou não viram.

Infelizmente eu não tenho tempo de elaborar um debate melhor que está precisando, mas preciso de uma posição da comunidade para ver o que fazer neste momento.

Sem critérios claros fica difícil moderar e mais fácil acharem que estou sendo autoritário, vai sempre desagradar um grupo.

Não digo individualmente, quero saber no geral para balizar minha decisão e quem para dois outros moderadores, e até a comunidade. Não pode cada um ficar atirando para um lado.

A decisão é importante e não importa o que aconteça vai mudar a forma de moderação, porque se eu não tiver apoio da comunidade para fechar ou reabrir o que eu entendo ser certo eu paro de fazer isso na maioria dos casos.

Este é um fenômeno recente, por 2 anos e meio minhas ações como moderador comunitário foram bem apoiadas, quase 1 ano de moderador eleito e tudo ia bem, agora tem havido discordâncias que vão além do AP que sempre quer sua pergunta aberta independente de qualquer critério.

Estou errando nos meus critérios?

Devamos seguir o que sempre foi definido no SOpt ou devemos mudar?

Eu estou entendendo errado o que sempre foi definido no SOpt?

Em coisas já definidas, devemos adotar o mesmo do SOen?

Estou em um dilema porque acho que a comunidade está falhando e o papel do moderador é suprir isto quando ocorre. Porém pode ser que a comunidade mudou de opinião. O que não pode é 2 ou 3 pessoas acharam uma coisa e isto se sobrepor ao que a comunidade quer.

## Edit

Que fique claro que não estou postando isso por mim e sim quero saber qual é a demanda da comunidade. O tom é de desabafo, mas o objetivo da pergunta é saber o que fazer.

Comment: Como nota lateral tenho percebido que algumas pessoas andam me sacaneando com votos ultimamente o que desanima moderar. Assim perde todos.

Comment: Pode dar exemplos de perguntas nessa situação?

Comment: @ramaral na verdade eu não queria pegar exemplos específicos. Tem até outras discussões recentes aqui no meta sobre isso. Vou passar o gatilho que me fez vir aqui, mas só vim porque já estava tendo outras antes, algumas idênticas. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223592/101

Comment: Na maioria dos casos justifica-se o fechamento desse tipo de perguntas. No entanto, nesse caso eu conseguiria responder sem dúvida do que é perguntado. Dei uma resposta a uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59257/2541) idêntica/duplicata. Enquanto não ficar claro que este tipo de pergunta( "eu quero fazer isso, se vira aí para responder tudo") deva ser fechada eu analiso caso a caso e sou condescendente com algumas.

Comment: @bigown nesta pergunta que vc citou no link, eu votaria para fechar simplesmente pela falta de esforço do usuário e de não ser capaz de reproduzir o problema dele. Mas, esta pergunta continua sendo respondível e ela é bem duvidosa. Em casos assim, eu sugiro que vc deixe a comunidade decidir, porque seu voto é unanime e algumas pessoas podem interpretar a situação de forma equivocada.

Comment: @bigown eu não sei bem o quão ampla é essa pergunta, mas em caso de mínima dúvida acho que devia deixar os utilizadores fecharem. Nesse caso especifico não sei responder porque não percebo do assunto.

Comment: Eu também achei a pergunta interessante, mas concordo com o @gato fecharia por não mostrar esforço. Tenho certeza que seria fechada por esse motivo, mas como você é moderador recebeu toda a "culpa", na qual tenho certeza também que não teria causado todo esse "problemas" caso fossem 5 a fechar e não apenas você.

Comment: Nao estresse. Foi a comunidade que o elegeu para ser moderador e erros todos cometos. Se for caso disso a comunidade pode reverter a sua decisao de fechamento de perguntas. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre o fechamento pode sempre falar com outro moderador ou deixar o fechamento para a comunidade também. Tome nota dos seus erros e aprenda com eles e siga em frente. É claro se vir que todas as suas decisoes estao a ser revertidas entao o problema é outro.

Comment: O assunto ser interessante ou não é outra coisa. A pergunta ser boa e se ela deve ficar aberta é que é a questão. O problema é que está sendo comum virar um drama eu fechar coisas sozinho. E estou fazendo bastante isso porque a comunidade não está fazendo e eu não sei se não estão por que discordam des fechamentos assim ou se só perderam a motivação para fazer. O que eu sei é que isso coincidiu um pouco com a nova barra que não incentiva o uso de filas, então pode ter relação.

Comment: `E estou fazendo bastante isso porque a comunidade não está fazendo e eu não sei se não estão por que discordam des fechamentos assim ou se só perderam a motivação para fazer.` Se calhar vale a pena levar o problema para outra questao do meta e alertar a comunidade para ser mais participativa. Está fora questao este ser um trabalho exclusivo da equipa de moderacao. Se bem que eu nao posso comentar muito sobre esse assunto >.<, uma vez que o meu trabalho é reduzido nas filas.

Comment: Um dos motivos desta pergunta é esta, ver se a comunidade se mexe, ou se ela quer que fique tudo na inércia.

Answer (score 11):

> É totalmente opinião pessoal, por favor se discordar comente e vote para baixo

Acho que **você** Bigown falha sim em alguns casos **isolados**, mas apenas alguns e tem pessoas levando isto como sendo absoluto, quando na verdade é relativo, todos podemos eventualmente falhar e nos equivocamos na hora de votar para *Fechar*, *Abrir*, *Cima* e *Baixo*.

Hoje mesmo eu percebi o quanto estava equivocado sobre um assunto que domino, os navegadores, ainda sim reconheci meu erro e sigo em frente, isso não me desqualifica (assim espero), o mesmo vale para ti, errar em algumas coisas não desqualifica o teu excelente trabalho com a comunidade, agora isso tudo não quer dizer que você não tenha o que melhorar, tem coisas que algumas pessoas disseram que do meu humilde ponto de vista são sim situações que estão erradas, eu mesmo mudei muito do começo do ano até aqui.

Não quer dizer que minhas falhas do começo do ano signifiquem que quem me criticou seja melhor do que eu, não pelo contrário, talvez alguns sejam melhores que eu e outros sejam mais falhos, a única coisa que o mais falhos que eu foram corretos foi naqueles momento que eu falhei, não significa que eles não falharam em outras ocasiões.

**Resumindo**, somos todos falhos, não importa o quão tenhamos boa vontade e nem conseguiremos atingir a perfeição, nenhum dos veteranos é perfeito, nenhum dos moderadores é perfeito, no entanto com certeza tem muito mais experiencia para julgar algo, mas vocês como moderadores e os veteranos devem saber receber criticas, eu ainda estou aprendendo a receber criticas é um caminho duro.

Então digo, não existe uma definição absoluta para o que é certo e o que é errado e nem atingiremos a perfeição, só somos uma comunidade melhor que muitos sites do mesmo tipo de assunto devido a termos alguns critérios, ainda sim vejo péssimas respostas no meio de ótimas respostas, o que importa é trabalhar e seguir.

### O que devemos fazer

Julgar cada pergunta isoladamente, existe um caminho bastante solido sobre fechamento e abertura de perguntas, mas não é porque é "solido" que não esteja sendo usado erroneamente, pra isto serve o META e a tag [pergunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica)

Se errou em fechar simplesmente basta reabrir e deixar o barco seguir em frente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas a dúvida é outra. Não perguntei se estou falhando, isso eu sei que falho aqui ou ali. Só que ultimamente estou fechando coisas que sempre foram fechadas pela comunidade, que até havia tensão se deixava aberto e agora tem ocorrido o contrário. Quero saber se mantenho a linha de sempre ou se agora é pra deixar quase tudo aberto. Eu não posso abrir um posta no meta a cada caso que tenho que fechar já que o comportamento da comunidade está parecendo inconsistente. Eu sei que estou pagando um preço quase pessoal por causa disto.

Comment: @bigown Eu posso ter começado a falar de falhas, mas o foco é entender que não existe definição de certo e errado, você Bigown é no máximo 80% certo em suas ações dentro da visão atual da comunidade, mas não quer dizer que será algo correto sempre que será correto para todos, não existe algo absoluto para tudo, cada pergunta e resposta deve ser analisada e pensada sim, ainda sim o ideal é fechar, fechar não é deletar eternamente, é apenas uma segurança, se a comunidade acha a pergunta especifica boa, vote para reabrir e não precisamos discutir sobre isso. Ao menos assim que eu penso ;)

Comment: @bigown nenhum de nós conseguiremos chegar aos seus 80% de "precisão", você e os moderadores estão mais apurados (80% é um numero meramente simbólico), vocês conhecem melhor tem acessos a dados, é mais valido confiar sim em suas ações, não quer dizer que sejam perfeitos, apenas isto, ao meu ver o melhor é sim fechar, mesmo que erroneamente e discutir no Meta, não existe solução unica, solida o suficiente e nem que consiga servir para todos casos. Mas é apenas opinião minha.

Comment: Até penso como você, mas anda tendo conflitos demais ultimamente e algumas pessoas parecem ter começado me punir por isso, não só houve aumento de negativos, mas também retirada de votos, votos evitados, votos em resposta concorrente ruim só para prejudicar a minha.

Comment: @bigown sim é justamente o que eu disse, essas pessoas também pensam que é algo absoluto, sendo que as coisas são relativas e por isso esta gerando algumas situações, elas estão querendo solução talvez aonde não precise de solução, se o seu fechamento foi errado, ok normal, vote para reabrir e abra uma pergunta no meta com a tag `pergunta-específica`, procurar solução para este tipo de problema é quase como procurar a arca-perdida, mesmo que achem a tal suposta arca talvez não sirva de nada, ou talvez ela nem exista. Mas é tudo opinião pessoal mesmo, eu posso estar inteiramente equivocado.

Comment: @bigown só pra constar, eu parei de receber upvotes e notei que certos usuários parecem receber votos gratuitamente, eu não sei se você teve essa sensação, não vou citar nomes, espero que de fato seja coincidência, mas se não for acho que só vocês e os moderadores podem definir o que houve, parece que o mesmo que ocorreu contigo anda a ocorrer comigo, talvez esteja havendo uma briga interna ou talvez seja realmente que minhas respostas não sejam lá grande coisa, mas vejo muitas respostas simplórias "por ai" com +4 instantâneos, nem sei dizer a causa disto.

Comment: Eu notei que anda acontecendo algumas coisas estranhas, e como eu acho que não tem o que fazer, entraremos em um desgaste natural, eu gostaria de evitar isso. Em um site pequeno é complicado porque sempre tem poucos querendo agir corretamente, então mesmo poucos não querendo assim, desequilibra fácil. Mas sempre que desconfiar pode sinalizar ou usar alguma forma para mostrar o que está percebendo. Dependendo do caso a moderação pode fazer algo. Acredito que tenha mesmo algo com os usuários mais ativos que gostam de fechar, de criticar o que tem de errado.

Comment: @bigown o tal do *facebook style* está oficialmente implementado no SOpt, esse é o único problema que me apercebo ao ler esta discussão...

Comment: Se vocês percebem votos em resposta concorrente ruim, eu no mínimo espero de vocês como membros de alta reputação que comentem na resposta ruim explicando o porque dela ser ruim. Infelizmente, nem todo mundo tem o mesmo senso crítico de vocês. O que para vocês pode ser ruim e incorreto, para membros novatos com reputação suficiente para *upvote* pode ser algo bom e eles apenas dão *upvote*.

Comment: Sobre o @bigown em particular, eu tenho uma admiração do cacete (pra não falar palavrão) pelas respostas bem detalhadas e técnicas que ele dá. Mas eu acho que muitos usuários são preguiçosos e acabam não lendo tudo o que ele posta (por serem textos longos, técnicos e detalhados), e acabam lendo a outra resposta por ser menor. Mesmo assim, acho que ele não deveria mudar o jeito dele de responder, estou apenas tentando justificar esses votos para respostas concorrentes. Talvez a reputação mínima para upvote deveria ser maior.

Comment: @Alisson eu comentava, ganhei muitos desafetos por causa disso, o efeito é quase sempre negativo, hoje em dia comento as vezes, ainda sim é necessário uma paciência enorme para explicar sem ferir os sentimentos e conseguir passar a barreira do egoismo que a maior parte das pessoas tem de entenderem que a qualidade exigida não é uma critica pessoal e sim algo para melhorar a comunidade. A cada dia vejo no minimo 5 respostas péssimas, a cada pessoa que vou comentar os problemas é exigido um esforço tremendo que leva as vezes horas para convencer o AP do erro dele...

Comment: ...as camadas de ego e vitimismo são muito grossas para conseguir passar as vezes, felizmente dá para dizer que isso é 50%, os outros 50% muitas vezes entendem, no entanto se ele torna a errar em uma nova pergunta e você torna a apontar seus erros, mesmo que da primeira vez ele tenha aceitado na boa, é bem provável que nas próximas ele comece a entender como perseguição, tem uns 2 usuários recentes que se sentiram assim quando apontei problemas em suas respostas. É cansativo, é frustante, o resultado de orientar essas pessoas quase sempre dá retorno zero.

Answer (score 3):

Eu fui um dos primeiros usuários do SO em português e sempre gostei da sua presença por aqui. Sobre a sua participação como usuário, não me lembro de jamais ter lhe dado um só voto negativo, pois os seus posts são simplesmente os melhores (isso se reflete na sua reputação).

Como moderador, eu acho que o seu trabalho é excelente. Você tem dois anos e meio de moderação e nesses cerca de mil dias eu acho que discordei sobre fechamentos três vezes. Dá uma média de uma vez a cada 330 dias. Em números, isso significa que eu concordo com você em 99,997% dos dias.

Isso é uma taxa de concordância muito alta. Em outra vida eu te pediria em casamento.

O fato de que duas das vezes em que eu discordei foram bem recentes não querem dizer nada sobre o seu trabalho como moderador. Eu disse que discordei, não que você está errado. Eu não tenho certeza se eu mesmo estou certo ou errado na maioria das vezes e é por isso que eu acredito que o correto é o consenso da comunidade. Eu acho que fui bem incisivo nesse ponto em alguns posts recentes dirigidos aos usuários mais novos da rede.

Seguindo esse raciocínio: as perguntas que eu pedi pra reabrir poderiam ser reabertas pelo consenso da comunidade, fluxo normal das coisas. Mas o consenso até agora foi deixar fechada como está.

Aliás, foi também consenso da comunidade te fazer moderador. Eu acredito que é pelo fato de que você é um dos melhores para esse papel. Eu sei que eu não faria um trabalho tão bom no seu lugar, sendo agressivo e parcial como eu sou.

Então, de coração: continue moderando como você está moderando. Por favor. Você é um exemplo, role-model mesmo, pra mim. Eu quero ser paciente, dedicado e educado como você é.

P.s.: eu me sinto meio que um bebê chorão pelo comentário que eu fiz na pergunta que você linkou nos comentários, e [nessa também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219078/criar-planilha-pelo-c-sem-ter-excel-instalado/) (fiz o dever de casa e mandei pra fila de revisão pra ser fechada de novo).

P.p.s.: eu acho que inclusive me contradisse quando pedi pra reabrir a pergunta sobre Excel e a pergunta sobre imagens. Porque anteriormente [eu já tinha dito que eu tenho uma opinião bem parecida com a sua](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6075/1658) sobre esses tipos de pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo confete, mas os melhores posts são de vários outros usuários, incluindo o seus, e de vários usuários que deixaram de contribuir por completo ou só dão alguns espasmos. A questão é que ultimamente várias pessoas andam discordando das minhas ações de moderação e eu acho que não mudei, acho que a comunidade está mudando, a questão é essa, eu quero saber qual é o norte. E não estou postando isso por causa só de um caso, tanto que não quis citar um. Na verdade eu acho que a comunidade não tem consenso algum.

Comment: Minha percepção é que a comunidade cansou e está deixando pra lá. E a receptividade deste post aqui no meta mostra isso. O final da sua resposta mostra o meu sentimento, acho que a comunidade está se contradizendo. Acho algumas outras coisas que vou evitar dizer porque estou sem tempo e precisa ser dita do jeito certo, com calma para não parecer um ataque, o que não é minha intenção, mas a comunidade não me parece estar tão saudável quanto estava tempos atrás. Por isso que estou cutucando o assunto. Mas é claro que eu é que posso estar errado. O que eu sei é que preciso ter parâmetro.

Comment: PS: Não fui eu quem negativou, ainda não li sua resposta, mas em breve lerei ;)

Comment: E eu até positivei :)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendo do SO, todos os usuários são moderadores, porém existe, digamos, moderadores dos moderadores (moderadores da comunidade), que são os moderadores eleitos pela comunidade. Entendo, que o papeis destes moderadores é de moderar onde a comunidade não tem poder para tal, como por exemplo,o mal uso das ferramentas do site e entre outras.

No caso de fechamento de perguntas de baixa qualidade, acredito que os moderadores por terem o tal **martelinho de ouro** devessem deixar para a comunidade decidir se fecha ou não, imagino que é pra isso que existe a fila de análise [Votos para Fechar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close)

> Que eu acho que é muito mal utilizada, pois as pessoas saem fechando sem ao menos fazer análise de fato.

Já os moderadores poderiam utilizar o seu martelo, em perguntas que claramente são ruins ou tem sérios problemas como spam, ofensas e etc.

Eu já vi perguntas que dá pra entender perfeitamente sendo fechada pois o moderador não conseguiu entender, mas os outros usuários além de mim, conseguimos entender e gerar resposta. Há cenários ainda que o tal moderador despreza as respostas por não estar de acordo com a ideologia dele.

Há outra situação que o moderador fecha a pergunta do AP e exige que ele modifique a pergunta para uma pergunta a nível de certificação.

As vezes me questiono quais são os parâmetros que os moderadores eleitos utilizam para fechar uma pergunta, pois há perguntas que não estão bem formuladas porém dá pra entender e responder (as vezes falta conhecimento do AP e que os veteranos poderiam auxiliá-lo a formular uma pergunta boa, ao invés disso os mesmo maltratam o AP que por sua vez fica irritado e não aceita mais conselhos), entretanto, estas perguntas são fechadas, mas outras perguntas que claramente o AP não quer nada com nada, fica lá aberta e acaba indo para a fila de análise (ou não).

Pra finalizar, o que eu acho que está acontecendo, pelo menos, desde quando eu voltei a colaborar, é que está tendo um excesso de moderação por parte dos moderadores eleitos.

Segundo a [Teoria da moderação](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), o que os moderadores fazem é o minimo possivel.

Comment: Só uma correção: o **martelinho de ouro** é como se chama a capacidade de alguns usuários com mais de 1000 pontos em determinada tag de fechar como duplicata sem precisar de 5 votos. Portanto, essa habilidade não é somente dos moderadores, aqueles que tem o losango no nome, eu e você também podemos ter :)

Comment: @Articuno, só por ser moderador você já ganha esse martelo certo? ou mesmo para os moderadores eles precisam atingir os 1000 pontos na TAG especifica?

Comment: O "martelo" o moderador tem pra tomar qualquer decisão de forma majoritária no site. Eu quis dizer que a gente chama de "martelo de ouro" é isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223725/28595 o guilherme não é moderador, mas fechou essa pergunta sozinho.

Comment: Ah de boa, isso eu sabia. Vlw pelo toque

Comment: Torno a dizer, se discorda de um fechamento basta votar para reabrir e talvez abrir uma pergunta no Meta para debater as causas, afinal de contas pode ter sido um erro por parte do moderador ou não. Para constar martelo de ouro é somente para duplicatas, ou seja se a pergunta é considerada duplicata dificilmente será um engano (claro que há exceções) pois não foi um problema de entender a pergunta e sim que já existe uma resposta ou uma pergunta sobre o assunto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, fechamento por duplicata, não tenho o que questionar, mas o problema não é este, as perguntas que estão sendo fechadas na maioria dos casos, são perguntas que, muitas vezes, um determinado moderador, acha que não está boa e vai lá e fecha, sendo que muitos outros usuários discordam destes fechamentos. Sim podemos utilizar a ferramenta para reabrir. Sim o moderador pode ter errado, mas persistir no erro... Como eu falei perguntas que tem sérios problemas, não há problema algum a interversão do moderador, mas há perguntas que eles deveriam deixar a comunidade decidir.

Comment: @TiagoS eu apenas estou explicando que martelo de ouro é apenas para DUP e sobre outros fechamentos somos uma comunidade, se discorda de algo basta vir aqui e debater e votar para reabrir. Eu mesmo queria responder 2 perguntas que foram fechadas, abri debates aqui no Meta ou conversei com algum moderador no chat e consegui reabrir e responder tranquilamente, [fechar **não** é do mal](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635), é apenas uma garantia para evitar problemas maiores que só os veteranos e moderadores sabem que pode vir a ocorrer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu sei que o fechar não é do mal, mas o que eu tentei levantar na minha resposta  é que alguns fechamentos estão sendo feito de forma arbitrária, utilizei a expressão martelo de ouro, para enfatizar esta forma de fechamento. O problema não é reabrir e sim fechar, que é o questionamento do Bigown.

Comment: Foi o que eu quis dizer tanto para você quanto para ele, isto não é um grande problema e é fácil de resolver, não temos porque fazer tempestade em copo d'água, é algo fácil de resolver e dialogar, o Meta e o Chat estão ai pra isto, o fechamento é uma segurança, melhor fechado evitando problemas e corrigir os problemas da pergunta enquanto fechado do que aberto e causando uma série de problemas (coisa que já vi muitas vezes), se a pergunta não for ruim e for um erro então vote para reabrir, o moderador pode ter visto algum possivel problema e pode ter sido um engano

Comment: mas se ele viu algo é melhor fechar e analisar e ter paciencia, como disse não é nem de longe um dos maiores problemas da comunidade, é algo fácil de resolver e conversar, como eu disse pro Bigown.