# Pergunta fechada, porém válida

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

A questão: [URL amigável cujo ID é o título da notícia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221801) é similar, se não uma duplicata, dessa outra:
[Url Amigavel com Mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75570/)

Votaram para fechar mesmo depois que eu editei para torná-la mais compreensível, apesar de já estar bem compreensível na forma original.

Eu discordo totalmente do fechamento. Não consigo ver onde que é "baseada em opinião".

Além do mais, existem outras iguais e abertas.

Fiz a busca por "url amigável sem id"
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amig%C3%A1vel+sem+id

Se buscar por outras palavras chave encontra mais resultados. Busquei apenas os termos mais óbvios mas muitos escrevem com termos errados e fica difícil encontrar.

Claro que entendo que nem sempre dá para pegar tudo e sempre vamos encontrar perguntas abertas e totalmente fora de escopo.. Não é esse o caso. Só quis mostrar que esse assunto **tem demanda**, é **válido**, dentro do escopo mas está sendo descartado.

Votei para reabrir quando estava pendente mas parece que foi negado e fecharam de vez. Só posso votar novamente daqui a uma semana.

Eu acho a que decisão de fechamento é equivocado.

O voto para reabrir quase nunca é bem avaliado pois quem avalia é quem votou para fechar e obviamente continuará votando para fechar... Não faz sentido.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é a primeira vez que acontece. Vejo isso direto. Conteúdo bom e relevante sendo fechado ou descartado.

Comment: `O voto para reabrir quase nunca é bem avaliado pois quem avalia é quem votou para fechar e obviamente continuará votando para fechar...`  isso ocorre porque as pessoas que são ativas nessas filas são praticamente as mesmas e são poucas, por isso acaba acontecendo isso.

Comment: exato.. é isso mesmo.

Comment: por isso tive receio de postar aqui.. já lascaram negativo.. rsrs é bem previsível. Abri como um debate e mesmo quem discorda do que postei, pode descrever no comentário ou em resposta, explicando por que discorda. Não estamos aqui para brigar ou disputar egos.. mas para debater e chegarmos num consenso.. por favor, tenha uma postura profissional.

Comment: Só não concordo com o motivo do fechamento, mas de qualquer a pergunta me parece dup, especificamente desta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164248/3635, talvez existam mais perguntas. É valida, mas é dup, sendo dup é melhor fechar mesmo. A não ser que tenha algum detalhe que não notei que diferencie em muito. Acho muito boa a sua atitude em abrir um debate para cada problema que encontrar deste tipo, mesmo que alguém tenha lhe dado downvote, afinal ajuda a formar ideias, eu pessoalmente acho que todos podemos nos equivocar ao fechar: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6209/3635 ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fechei a pergunta como duplicata. Essa é uma das perguntas mais frequentes no site.

Comment: Era isso mesmo o correto.

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver, tanto que votei como tal, sim, é uma questão baseada em opiniões. Primariamente pela palavra "melhor", tanto que na pergunta há o comentário "melhor forma" ou "de que forma". São coisas bem distintas. Da primeira, a pergunta é baseada em opinião, da segunda, duplicata. Para definir se algo é melhor demanda métricas. Melhor em relação a quê? E isso não está explícito na pergunta. Pode ser melhor em tempo de resposta, melhor em menos número de linhas de código, melhor em questão de escabilidade, etc. Dependendo da métrica definida, a melhor forma pode variar. O que você define como melhor será baseado em opinião enquanto não definido na pergunta. Se muito bem definido isso, sim, poderá gerar uma discussão saudável para a comunidade.

> O voto para reabrir quase nunca é bem avaliado pois quem avalia é quem votou para fechar e obviamente continuará votando para fechar.

Essa afirmação não é válida pois parte de uma premissa errada. Eu particularmente sempre avalio com atenção a fila de reabertura, tendo eu votado no fechamento ou não. A questão mesmo é se a edição resolveu o problema ou não. Dada que a pergunta se manteve fechada, mais pessoas concordaram que a edição não resolveu o problema. O fato de serem as mesmas pessoas que fecharam avaliarem a reabertura não interfere em nada.

Faz sentido e tem funcionado muito bem em praticamente todas as perguntas. Não se pode avaliar uma situação com apenas um caso particular. E ao meu ver, mesmo nesta pergunta funcionou.